# TypeScript: augmenting built-in types

Tags: typescript

how does one augment one of the 'built-in' types? eg Array?

In JS, I'd do something like

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function () { ... };
```

what's the equivalent in TypeScript?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Types are 'open ended' in TypeScript, so you can just write:

```
interface Array {
  shuffle: () => any; // <-- Whatever signature you want.
}
```

And then the type is expanded to include the new function (and you can assign a function matching the signature to it).

Note however that extending the built-in types (those in lib.d.ts - such as Array) has an issue currently in the language service, as it caches those internally for perf reasons.  Do the workaround I wrote-up at http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/4 to extend the built-in types without errors in the language service in VS.

Comment: Can we have the link to the work-around updated pls?

Comment: Or just typed into the answer where it should be?

Comment: Hey all, found the answer on the WayBack Machine! https://web.archive.org/web/20180115225023/http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/4