# How to handle warnings for proprietary/custom properties of built-in objects in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am using Personas which relies on the [proprietary property `navigator.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/navigator.id). Since this property is not standard, the TypeScript compiler generates the following warning:

```
$ tsc home.ts --out my_ts_generated_code.js
/Users/..../home.ts(27,18): The property 'id' does not exist on value of type 'Navigator'
```

But the .js file is successfully generated and runs on the FF15 browser without any warning/error message.
I also include a polyfill for `navigator.id`, as instructed by the documentation, so `navigator.id` will definitely by available in every browser.

Could someone suggest me how to deal with this warning?

**index.html**

```
<!-- some HTML omit above -->
<script src="https://login.persona.org/include.js"></script>
<script src="my_ts_generated_code.js"></script>
<button class="btn" id="signin">Sign in</button>
<button class="btn" id="signout">Sign out</button>
<!-- some HTML omit below -->
```

**home.ts**

```
declare var $;

class Student {
    fullname : string;
    constructor(public firstname, public middleinitial, public lastname) {
        this.fullname = firstname + " " + middleinitial + " " + lastname;
    }
}

interface Person {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
}

function greeter(person : Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstname + " " + person.lastname;
}

var user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");

$(function() {
    $('#signin').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        navigator.id.request();
    });

    $('#signout').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        navigator.id.logout();
    });
    //document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
});
```

Comment: What is `navigator`? Where is it coming from? How is it declared?

Comment: @Sidharth: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/navigator.id ... it's a non-standard property.

Comment: @FelixKling - Tks for the info. Never used `id` on `navigator`. In fact, i try to stay away from using `navigator` all the time!

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with TypeScript? If you are really using the script for Persona authentication, it might be helpful for others to add this information to your question and change the title accordingly.

Comment: @FelixKling - This is my snippet of code. I have another tested TypeScript code that I do not include in question.

Comment: Ok, but if the question is not about TypeScript, then you should not tag it as such ;)

Comment: @FelixKling - The question still related with TypeScript because the .ts file has code both TypeScipt and Javascript code

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701732/typescript-augmenting-built-in-types. I honestly recommend to use a different title and/or describe the problem different, like "How to avoid warnings for proprietary/custom properties on built-in objects" and explain what you are trying to do (integrating Personas) and it exhibits this problem (it uses `navigator.id`).

Comment: @FelixKling I change the title as your suggestion

Comment: I took the liberty to reformulate your post to make the problem clearer, because I think this is a good question. Please feel free to roll back or adjust it. I don't think the compiled code is needed for this problem.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

1) 
You can reinterpret navigator prop.

```
(<any>navigator).id.request();
```

2) 
You can declare id prop youself

mycompany.lib.d.ts

```
interface Navigator {
  id: any
}
```

app.ts

```
navigator.id.request();
```

see this video http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Anders-Hejlsberg-Introducing-TypeScript/ There Anders tell as jQuery.UI add new methods to jQuery (see 46 min)

Comment: I went with Option 2 since it seems like the "Typescript Way" and helps minimize technical debt.

Answer (score 2):

Add checks like `if(navigator.id != null && typeof navigator.id != 'undefined')` before stmt where navigator.id is referred

Comment: This will guard against undefined id at runtime, but the compiler will still complain that it breaks the interface. @Jack128's answer is good - add the interface definition. Better still, write a declaration header for the actual interface rather than just saying `navigator.id : any`.