# How do you explicitly set a new property on `window` in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I setup global namespaces for my objects by explicitly setting a property on `window`.

```
window.MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};
```

TypeScript underlines `MyNamespace` and complains that:

> The property 'MyNamespace' does not exist on value of type 'window'
>   any"

I can make the code work by declaring `MyNamespace` as an ambient variable and dropping the `window` explicitness but I don't want to do that.

```
declare var MyNamespace: any;

MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};
```

How can I keep `window` in there and make TypeScript happy?

As a side note I find it especially funny that TypeScript complains since it tells me that `window` is of type `any` which by definitely can contain anything.

Comment: Some of the answers are the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412736/how-can-i-tackle-this-edit).

Comment: The answer [stackoverflow.com/a/47130953](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47130953) also has a link to the TypeScript documentation: [Augmenting global/module scope from modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html#augmenting-globalmodule-scope-from-modules).

Comment: Typescript global declarations are more subtle than you might think. For a better understanding, I recommend these answers from other questions: [Create a global variable in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56984941/61624) [Using globalThis in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68452689/61624)

Answer (score 1494, accepted):

I just found the answer to this in [another Stack Overflow question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12703866/31308).

```
declare global {
    interface Window { MyNamespace: any; }
}

window.MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};
```

Basically, you need to extend the existing `window` interface to tell it about your new property.

Comment: Note the capital W in Window. That tripped me up.

Comment: I couldn't get this to compile with tsc 1.0.1.0. Blake Mitchell's answer did work for me, though.

Comment: I needed to test for PointerEvent as a feature check, which TypeScript didn't like so adding the interface line solved my problem without declaring the variable and thus not affecting the test (TypeScript 1.5.3.0)
Thanks

Comment: In the newest Angular versions, just use the first line. This worked for me.

Comment: We should probably use an optional property like this: `interface Window { MyNamespace?: any; }`

Comment: The `declare global { interface Window { ... } }` works with TypeScript 2.5.2, no need for `.d.ts` file as mentioned above

Comment: At first typescript told me: `error TS1234: An ambient module declaration is only allowed at the top level in a file.`, when I put it at the top of the file, it did fix that error, so you might have to do that as well.

Comment: I'm getting "TS2339: Property 'MyNamespace' does not exist on type 'Window'. I'm using window in a different file.

Comment: Trick: you must add some import (like `import * as React from 'react';`) if you put these in index.d.ts

Comment: `declare interface Window { __GLOBAL_VAR__: any }`

Comment: if you get the error "TS2339: Property 'MyNamespace' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'." then add `export {}` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: This answer says "extend the existing `window` interface` - not to be pedantic, but this is declarataion merging, not extension: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html. In case anyone wants to know about the limitations and trade-offs.

Comment: If you need to import an external type, check this answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40204572

Comment: Just do this: https://medium.com/@ohansemmanuel/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript-e144cfecf8e7

Answer (score 568):

To keep it dynamic, just use:

```
(<any>window).MyNamespace
```

Note that this may not work with TSX because the compiler might think that the `<any>` is a TSX element. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38964459/1250319) for type assertion that is compatible with TSX.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this in a tsx file?

Comment: @martin: The <any> makes it explicit, so it works just fine, I believe. Others: If you are using Typescript with React or other JSX environment (resulting in TSX syntax) you'll have to use `as` instead of `<>`. See @david-boyd's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript#38964459).

Comment: I had to use (window as any).MyNamespace

Comment: Similarly for `this` - `return (<any> this)['something in scope']`

Comment: I have had to disable tslint on that line with `/* tslint:disable */`

Comment: This is by far my favorite solution, as someone someone who's used to working in vanilla JS and being able to access the window object without any problems. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46025351/1295378 which elaborates further

Comment: I also used this style, but now I switch to eslint (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/tslint-eslint-migration) and this style leads to some warnings: First you get 
`Use 'as any' instead of '<any>'.eslint@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions` and when switch to `as any` you get `Unexpected any. Specify a different type.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any` I know I could disable those warnings but I would like keep it clean without disabling if possible.

Comment: can also do this once into a variable like `var anyWindow = <any>window;` and then use the `anyWindow` like you would `window` after that.

Comment: This was a bad edit @Retsam, the version you edited to is already an answer below, and you fundamentally changed the answer. Please keep this as `(<any>window).MyNamespace`

Comment: @Daniel The `<Type> value` syntax is just an old, legacy syntax for the new, preferred, (and works in JSX files)`value as Type` syntax.  They're completely identical in behavior and it's confusing for this answer to show the old legacy syntax which has mostly been scrubbed from TS's documentation.  

Yes, this makes it fundamentally the same as an answer given later: but it seems bad for the top voted answer to use the worse syntax.

Especially since the two most upvoted comments are people having issue with this answer.

Comment: @Retsam But the question is not about TSX, it's about TS. And it's not the top voted answer, it's the second top-most voted answer. It's also valid TS. I also don't think it would be good practise to change every highly rated answer to the "best" answer just because it's highly rated. This defeats the purpose of voting and posting answers.

Comment: Let me try changing the answer to give helpful context, without changing the actual answer, let me know what you think @Retsam

Comment: @Daniel TSX was the original motivation for introducing a new syntax, but the `as` syntax is now the recommended syntax, regardless of whether you're writing TSX or not.  There's just no reason for the language to have two identical syntaxes for doing the same thing, and it's confusing for people who aren't familiar with this legacy syntax to see answers using it.  Saying "use this if you're using JSX" is just not necessary.

Comment: Yes, it makes this answer identical to a second answer, but honestly, that person shouldn't have put up an answer that's identical except for using a different syntax - they should have edited this answer to update to the modern syntax.

Comment: I've put up my own edit as a compromise - this lists both answers, so it's not identical to the other answer, but primarily lists the newer, preferred syntax and drops the mention of TSX.

Comment: This makes absolute no sense @Retsam, your logic for changing this one is because it was "the highest answer" on this question but that's not true at all. Also the answer already exists. Reverting it.

Comment: I put this question to a meta post @Retsam https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412736/1250319 and one excellent point is that Stackoverflow is about *accumulating* knowledge, not *destroying* it. The syntax is old yes but not deprecated. Do not edit again please.

Comment: I believe taking this approach doesn't work well with the spirit of TypeScript. When I write my projects in TS, I'm trying to improve my ability to spot errors before the user does. This approach merely silences the type checker, but doesn't ensure correct usage of the member which is being defined.

Answer (score 309):

Using Svelte or TSX?  None of the other answers were working for me.

Here's what I did:

```
(window as any).MyNamespace
```

Comment: Same as [`(<any> window).MyNamespace`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30740935/4554883) actually

Comment: It is the same except when using TSX, because the `<any>` gets interpreted as JSX, not a type cast.

Comment: Thanks @David, this worked like a charm with new Create React App and typescript version, Previously this was working : (<any>window).MyNamespace, but now it is breaking in new typescript version 3.5.x.

Comment: window as any? Then why would you use typescript? Just use Javascript x)

Comment: @MarcoLe For instance, Angular uses TypeScript and if you want to develop a logger that can switch properties on it at runtime, you can do so in the browser's dev console with this technique.

Comment: Funny how people use Typescript and then silence it. It's as good as not using it at all. And to think that these answers are the most upvoted ones! Sounds promising...

Comment: It's worth noting the big downside of this solution. You're turning off type checking for this part of your codebase. Make sure you're comfortable and ensure disabling TypeScript's ability to warn you of problems.

Answer (score 232):

***As of TypeScript ^3.4.3, this solution no longer works***

Or...

you can just type:

```
window['MyNamespace']
```

And you won’t get a compile error and it works the same as typing `window.MyNamespace`.

Comment: but you will probably get a tslint error... If you have one of course

Comment: This completely flies in the face of strong typing, the whole idea behind TypeScript.

Comment: @user1334007 using globals does as well. However, some legacy code requires it.

Comment: @user1334007 this is the example when you need this stuff: http://andrewhfarmer.com/aws-sdk-with-webpack/

Comment: how about when we have to call a method?

Comment: @Ramesh `window['MyNamespace']()` (just add brackets)

Comment: @nathancahill Global variables have nothing to do with strong typing! You can have strong, static typing even if your project uses global variables.

Comment: I couldn't do `window:Window`  `window.Promise`, but I can `window['Promise']`

Comment: Does not work in `^3.4.3`. `TypeScript error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Window' has no index signature.  TS7017`

Comment: @Cody No, not good. If you don't want strong typing, just don't use TypeScript! Bastardizing the language to get around it's basic features is just foolish.

Comment: I really must echo @Auspex. TypeScript isn't a thing you should be trying to get around. If you're using TS, embrace it and get the types right. If you don't want to do that, don't use TypeScript. If you're being forced to use it but don't want to, make the case to your manager to switch away from TS, or get help getting the typings right. It's exceedingly unprofessional and petulant to muddy and disrupt a TS codebase  as a passive aggressive swipe at strong/static typing.

Answer (score 142):

Globals are "evil" :) I think the best way to also have the portability is:

First you export the interface: (for example, *./custom.window.ts*)

```
export interface CustomWindow extends Window {
    customAttribute: any;
}
```

Second, you import

```
import {CustomWindow} from './custom.window.ts';
```

Third, cast the global variable window with CustomWindow:

```
declare let window: CustomWindow;
```

In this way you also don't have a red line in a different IDE if you use it with existent attributes of the *window* object, so at the end try:

```
window.customAttribute = 'works';
window.location.href = '/works';
```

Tested with TypeScript 2.4.x and newest!

Comment: you might want to expand on why globals are evil. In our case we're using a non standardized API on the window object. It is polyfilled for now. Is that truely evil?

Comment: @MathijsSegers i don't know especially your case but.. about globals are evil is not only about javascript.. is in every language.. some reason are:
- You can't apply well design pattern 
- Memory and performance issue (You have them everywhere, try to attach something to String Object and see what happens when you do new String)
- Name collision causing side effect on code.. (especially on javascript that have async nature)

I can continue but i think you can image the rest...

Comment: @onabi I'm literally talking about a feature of the browser. It's globally available since it's the browser. You really would suggest it's still wrong to go for global definitions? I mean we could implement Ponyfills but this would bloat browsers which actually support the feature (e.g. fullscreen api).

That said I don't believe that all globals are evil perse.

Comment: @MathijsSegers in my opinion the global variable should be avoid to be used or modified where we can.. is true that window is available since browser exist but is also true that was in mutation all the time.. so if for example we define now window.feature = 'Feature'; and this is used in massive way on code.. what happen if window.feature is added by browsers on all code this feature is override.. anyway i gave a explanation of my sentence is not to go against you.. regards...

Comment: Globals are not "evil"; there is a place for such things, otherwise they would be removed from programming languages.  Sometimes a global variable really is the best way to implement something.  What is evil, is "overuse of globals".

Comment: Depending on the use-case of course, I prefer this approach too since it allows me to type non-standard API without making it available across the code base. Additionally if you are working on a library you might not want to alter the global scope as your users might start depending on the existence of these types.

Comment: Globals are not evil, there is a lot of valid use cases for them, like making accessible a library with a public api: eg `window.MyAwesomeLib = someObject;` or a polyfill, it's only evil if you declare every single one of your private vars on it, because you pollute the window object and may run into naming conflicts. But almost nobody does that anyways, and definitely nobody using typescript

Comment: When using this on a Vue component I get a TS error on `declare` saying `Modifiers cannot appear here. ts(1184)`. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: If globals are not evil, they might be dangerous, as stated above by @onalbi

Comment: In 2023, you should be importing modules instead of adding them to the window object.

Comment: "cast the global variable `window` with `CustomWindow`" Hmm, this isn't a cast. Instead you're *shadowing* the global variable with a (nonexistent) *local* variable named `window`. The compiler now believes that `window` is some local variable unrelated to the global `window` variable, and so it lets you choose its type. At runtime only the global variable exists so it works there too.  It's essentially a strategic deception, not a cast.  Do you mind [edit]ing this answer to describe how this actually works? Or do you mind if I do it?

Answer (score 105):

It's straightforward:

File *src/polyfills.ts*

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    myCustomFn: () => void;
  }
}
```

File *my-custom-utils.ts*

```
window.myCustomFn = function () {
  ...
};
```

If you're using [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), you also needed to change the following setting in the IDE before your new [polyfills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) pick up:

```
> File
> Settings
> Languages & Frameworks
> TypeScript
> check 'Use TypeScript Service'.
```

Comment: `declare global` is the trick, and this answer is not really specific to Angular CLI...

Comment: yeah. its the correct one.

Comment: Note that, depending on your setup and your declaration files, you might need `declare interface Window` without the `declare global` wrapper.

Answer (score 84):

The accepted answer is what I used to use, but with TypeScript 0.9.* it no longer works. The new definition of the `Window` interface seems to completely replace the built-in definition, instead of augmenting it.

I have taken to doing this instead:

```
interface MyWindow extends Window {
    myFunction(): void;
}

declare var window: MyWindow;
```

**UPDATE:** With TypeScript 0.9.5 the accepted answer is working again.

Comment: This works also with modules as used by TypeScript 2.0.8.

Example:

`export default class MyClass{
    foo(){
       ...
    }
    ...
}`

`interface MyWindow extends Window{
    mc: MyClass
}`

`declare var window: MyWindow`
`window.mc = new MyClass()`


Then you can call foo() e.g. from the Chrome Dev Tools console like


`mc.foo()`

Comment: This is a very nice answer if you don't want to declare something as global. On the other side, you need to call `declare var...` in every file you need.

Comment: Plus one for this approach because in this case you don't conflict with the other packages which extend the global window in the monorepo.

Comment: Thank you! Best answer IMO. One should not override `Window` for the simple fact that it *is not* a vanilla window. Just circumventing type checking or trying to fool TS also isn't the way to do it.

Answer (score 71):

If you need to extend the `window` object with a custom type that requires the use of `import`, you can use the following method:

**window.d.ts**

```
import MyInterface from './MyInterface';

declare global {
    interface Window {
        propName: MyInterface
    }
}
```

See [Global Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) in the 'Declaration Merging' section of the Handbook.

Answer (score 57):

Create a file called `global.d.ts`, e.g., `/src/@types/global.d.ts`, and then define an interface like:

```
interface Window {
  myLib: any
}
```

Reference: *[Global .d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html)*

Answer (score 49):

Most of the other answers are not perfect.

- Some of them just suppress the type inference for show.
- Some of the others only care about global variables as namespaces, but not as interfaces/classes

I also encountered a similar problem this morning. I tried so many "solutions" on Stack Overflow, but none of them produced absolutely no type errors and enabled triggering type jumping in the IDE ([WebStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#WebStorm) or [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)).

Finally, from *[Allow module definitions to be declared as global variables #3180](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3180#issuecomment-102523512)*

I found a reasonable solution to **attach typings for a global variable that acts as interface/class and namespace both**.

The example is below:

```
// typings.d.ts
declare interface Window {
    myNamespace?: MyNamespace & typeof MyNamespace
}

declare interface MyNamespace {
    somemethod?()
}

declare namespace MyNamespace {
    // ...
}
```

The code above merges the typings of namespace `MyNamespace` and interface `MyNamespace` into the global variable `myNamespace` (the property of *window*).

Answer (score 37):

I don't need to do this very often. The only case I have had was when using [Redux DevTools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) with middleware.

I simply did:

```
const composeEnhancers = (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
```

Or you could do:

`let myWindow = window as any;`

And then `myWindow.myProp = 'my value';`

Comment: In this case you can also install the npm package, which contains all the definitions - [as specified in the docs](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#11-basic-store)

Comment: You can do this, but that's not the answer to the question, but rather a workaround

Comment: Thanks to this, I could enable redux tools properly under typescript by using (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())

Answer (score 23):

From the version 3.4, TypeScript has supported `globalThis`. See *[Type-checking for globalThis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#type-checking-for-globalthis)*.

*From the above link*:

```
// in a global file:
var abc = 100;
// Refers to 'abc' from above.
globalThis.abc = 200;
window.abc = 300; // window object can also be used.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/G4QwTgBCBGDGEF4IEYAMqDcAoA5gGwHtoQ8AVACwEsBnAOhniQCZ1sB3SgOwBMC364iCAGZWWLEA)

A "global" file is a file which does not have any import/export statements. So the declaration `var abc;` can be written in *.d.ts*.

Comment: Yes but does it declare the variable on the window object, which is the question asked? I highly doubt that

Comment: It does. `lib.d.ts` declares `window` as type `Windows & globalThis`, meaning the two types get merged together.

Answer (score 22):

After finding answers around, I think this page might be helpful:

*[Global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation)*

I am not sure about the history of declaration merging, but it explains why the following could work.

```
declare global {
    interface Window { MyNamespace: any; }
}

window.MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};
```

Answer (score 18):

If you are using TypeScript 3.x, you may be able to omit the `declare global` part in the other answers and instead just use:

```
interface Window {
  someValue: string
  another: boolean
}
```

This worked with me when using TypeScript 3.3, [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) and [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/).

Comment: Does not work in `^3.4.3`. This answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/42841166/1114926

Comment: *"TSLint has been deprecated as of 2019. Please see this issue for more details: Roadmap: TSLint → ESLint."*. [Source](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/).

Answer (score 18):

Using create-react-app v3.3 I found the easiest way to achieve this was to extend the `Window` type in the auto-generated `react-app-env.d.ts`:

```
interface Window {
    MyNamespace: any;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

TypeScript does not perform typechecking on string properties.

```
window["newProperty"] = customObj;
```

Ideally, the global variable scenario should be avoided. I use it sometimes to debug an object in the browser console.

Answer (score 17):

```js
// In typings.d.ts(is Global)
export declare global {
    interface Window {
        __PUBLIC__: string;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked nicely for me and feels an explicit way of defining the type globally where that's applicable. I'll add that in my case I wanted to add `Cypress` and `app` which had imported types. I was able to nicely achieve this by importing both types from their respective libs and declaring the attributes accordingly:

```
import { Cypress } from 'cypress';
import { ComponentPublicInstance } from 'vue';

// Add Cypress and app to global window for testing
export declare global {
  interface Window {
    Cypress: Cypress;
    app: ComponentPublicInstance;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Here's how to do it, if you're using [TypeScript Definition Manager](https://github.com/typings/typings)!

```
npm install typings --global
```

Create `typings/custom/window.d.ts`:

```typescript
interface Window {
  MyNamespace: any;
}

declare var window: Window;
```

Install your custom typing:

```
typings install file:typings/custom/window.d.ts --save --global
```

Done! Use it! TypeScript won't complain any more:

```typescript
window.MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};
```

Comment: FWIW `typings` was made obsolete with Typescript 2.0 (mid 2016), and has been archived by the owner.

Answer (score 16):

Using

```
window["MyNamespace"] = window["MyNamespace"] || {};
```

should be all right as it is using a string property, but if you really want to have a separated window and organised your code, you can **extend** the window object:

```
interface MyNamespacedWindow extends Window {
    MyNamespace: object;
}

declare var window: MyNamespacedWindow;
```

Comment: I like your second solution, but it throws a TS error on `declare` saying `Modifiers cannot appear here. ts(1184)`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

First you need to declare the window object in the current
scope. Because TypeScript would like to know the type of the
object. Since the *window* object is defined somewhere else, you can not redefine it.

But you can declare it as follows:

```
declare var window: any;
```

This will not redefine the window object nor will it create another variable with name `window`. This means *window* is defined somewhere else and you are just referencing it in the current scope.

Then you can refer to your MyNamespace object simply by:

```
window.MyNamespace
```

Or you can set the new property on the `window` object simply by:

```
window.MyNamespace = MyObject
```

And now the TypeScript won’t complain.

Answer (score 11):

[2022]:We have to extend the "window" object in our React or Nextjs project .
We can use the following step to solve this issue.

- Make a folder inside src folder name as types.
- Make a file inside types folder name as index.d.ts
- write this code inside index.d.ts file.
  [image]

  ```
  export {};
   declare global {
     interface Window {
      NameSpace: any;
     }

   }
   window.NameSpace= window.NameSpace|| {};
  ```

[image]
save this file.

**Now one last change .**

Change the "*tsConfig.json*" file. to inherit both the node module type and our types.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   ...
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
    ],
 ....
}
```

[image]

Comment: of all the things I tried, this worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

## Full & Short answer

### 1- Add `typeRoots` property to `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["src/@types", "node_modules/@types"]
    ...
  }
}
```

### 2- Extend `Window` type

```
// file: src/@types/global.d.ts

declare global {
    interface Window { customProperty: <type>; }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For reference (this is the correct answer):

Inside a `.d.ts` definition file

```
type MyGlobalFunctionType = (name: string) => void
```

If you work in the browser, you add members to the browser's window context by reopening Window's interface:

```
interface Window {
  myGlobalFunction: MyGlobalFunctionType
}
```

The same idea for Node.js:

```
declare module NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    myGlobalFunction: MyGlobalFunctionType
  }
}
```

Now you declare the root variable (that will actually live on window or global):

```
declare const myGlobalFunction: MyGlobalFunctionType;
```

Then in a regular `.ts` file, but imported as side-effect, you actually implement it:

```
global/* or window */.myGlobalFunction = function (name: string) {
  console.log("Hey !", name);
};
```

And finally use it elsewhere in the codebase, with either:

```
global/* or window */.myGlobalFunction("Kevin");

myGlobalFunction("Kevin");
```

Answer (score 8):

For those who want to set a computed or dynamic property on the `window` object, you'll find that not possible with the `declare global` method. To clarify for this use case

```
window[DynamicObject.key] // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type Window has no index signature
```

You might attempt to do something like this

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    [DyanmicObject.key]: string; // error RIP
  }
}
```

The above will error though. This is because in TypeScript, interfaces do not play well with computed properties and will throw an error like

```
A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol
```

To get around this, you can go with the suggest of casting `window` to `<any>` so you can do

```
(window as any)[DynamicObject.key]
```

Answer (score 7):

Make a custom interface that extends the Window and add your custom property as optional.

Then, let the customWindow use the custom interface, but valued with the original window.

It's worked with the TypeScript 3.1.3.

```
interface ICustomWindow extends Window {
  MyNamespace?: any
}

const customWindow:ICustomWindow = window;

customWindow.MyNamespace = customWindow.MyNamespace {}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(window as { test: string } & Window & typeof globalThis).test = `Hello World`;
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to use this in an Angular (6) library today and it took me a while to get this to work as expected.

In order for my library to use declarations, I had to use the `d.ts` extension for the file that declares the new properties of the global object.

So in the end, the file ended up with something like:

`/path-to-angular-workspace/angular-workspace/projects/angular-library/src/globals.d.ts`

Once created, don't forget to expose it in your `public_api.ts`.

That did it for me.

Answer (score -3):

I use without declarate.
My example looks like:

[image]

Answer (score -5):

TypeScript prevents accessing an object without assigning a type that has the desired property or
already assigned to `any`, so you can use optional chaining:

```
window?.MyNamespace =  'value'
```

Comment: this doesn't remove the typescript warning.

Comment: The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access. ts(2779)

Comment: (window as any)?.MyNamespace =  'value'

Comment: Evaluating `window?.MyNamespace = 'value'` in JS will actually result in an error (e.g. in Chrome) `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`, so there is a reason why the warning should be there.
Whether an actual JS error will be thrown depends on the TS version/config though. For example, for TS4.7.4 targetting ES2019, the output in JS is `window === null || window === void 0 ? void 0 : window.MyNamespace = 'value';` which doesn't throw an error. For TS5.0.4 targetting ES2020 the output is `window?.MyNamespace = 'value';` so there's a runtime error.