# Typescript: How to declare an interface when also importing a library?

Tags: typescript

I used stackoverflow [How do you explicitly set a new property on `window` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript) to extend window.
The code looks like the following:

```
interface Window { appConfig: any; }
window.appConfig = window.appConfig || {};
```

Everything works fine.

When i add the line

```
import _ = require('lodash');
```

I get an error

> Error TS2339: Property 'appConfig' does not exist on type 'Window'.

How can i fix this issue?

I work with typescript 1.6.2

Comment: for window i usually just make it an any instead of trying to extend it. `(<any>window).appConfig = (<any>window).appConfig || {};` Here is a possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript

Comment: this is not a duplicate. I am not asking about how to extend window. I am asking about why the import statement brings the error

Comment: have you tried doing the import above the interface? maybe lodash is overwriting or creating their own interface for window?

Comment: Yes. You can see it in the typescript playground

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using external modules, interfaces found in `.ts` files won't be merged with interfaces found in `.d.ts` files. So in this case, it's not working because the `Window` interface in the `.ts` file isn't merged with the `Window` interface found in `lib.d.ts`. That's due to the nature of external modules.

To fix it, move...

```
interface Window { appConfig: any; }
```

...into a definition file (`.d.ts`).