# Create binding based on external JS

Tags: ffi, reason, bucklescript

In [this](https://medium.com/@Hehk/binding-a-library-in-reasonml-e33b6a58b1b3) post, the autor teaches how to make a binding from a NodeJS library to Reason. However, I want to create a binding for [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript), which can't be installed through NPM. Rather, it's usually loaded in the bottom of `<body>` with `<script>` tag.

Also, Google Maps Javascript API only exports it's functions inside the function that has been passed as argument in url (`callback=funcName`). Will this work in Reason the same way as in raw JS?

How can I make this binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is installed as a global, so you'd just [bind to them as ordinary globals](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/bind-to-global-values.html). And since Reason functions generate ordinary JavaScript functions the following is more or less equivalent to the example in the documentation you've linked:

```rust
type map;
[@bs.new] [@bs.scope ("google", "maps")] external make : (Dom.element, Js.t({..})) => map = "Map";

let initMap = () => {
  let map = make(mapElement, {
    "center": { "lat": -34.397, "lng": 150.644 },
    "zoom": 0
  });
};
```

Comment: I'm going to test it and give you a response asap

Comment: It worked, I only had to add a line binding the callback function to `window`, based on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575947/1924257. I'm going to edit your answer and accept it.