# TypeScript Extend 'Window' wtih TSLint Compatibility?

Tags: typescript, tslint

### What I'm Trying to Do...

I'm attempting to **extend the Window interface** using TypeScript but also want to **follow the [recommended TSLint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/configs/recommended.ts) rules**.

### What Searches Have Produced/Suggested...

Other StackOverflow questions such as [How do you explicitly set a new property on `window` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript#) largely recommend extending the `Window` interface which seems like a preferred solution to using `(window as any)` everywhere you reference `Window`.

### The Issue I'm Facing...

When using what seems like the ideal solution...

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        MY_GLOBAL_VAR1: string; // reference with window.MY_GLOBAL_VAR1
        MY_GLOBAL_VAR2: bool; // reference with window.MY_GLOBAL_VAR2
    }
}
```

... the **[recommended TSLint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/configs/recommended.ts) throws an error because of the ["no-namespace"](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-namespace/) rule**.

### The Plea For Help...

My goal is to **not** override this rule if possible.  Has anyone found a solution to satisfy extending Window in a [recommended TSLint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/configs/recommended.ts)-compatible way?

Comment: What version of TSLint are you using? This looks like a fixed bug: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/1833

Comment: I'm using 5.4.2 but see there's a 5.4.3.  I updated and it's the same because I'm not utilizing the "allow-declarations" since that's not part of the recommended tslint.  The recommendation is still `"no-namespace": true`,