# Import EventDrops (D3.js) into Angular 2

Tags: angular, d3.js

For a project I'm working on, I found an [interesting library](https://github.com/marmelab/EventDrops) that I would like to import, but I don't know how.

The project is based on Angular 2, it runs through a SPA template through ASP.NET Core (in case it matters) and it gets built by webpack.

Until now I installed both D3 and EventDrops through NPM, than imported them into my component.ts file like this:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as EventDrops from 'event-drops';
```

First I tested the D3.js import by adding:

```
ngOnInit() {
    var eventDropsChart = d3.select("#visual");
    console.log(eventDropsChart);
    ...
}
```

It seems to work, so I tried the next step that is:

```
var eventDropsChart = d3.chart.eventDrops();
```

But it does not work, because

> TS2339: Property 'chart' does not exist on type 'typeof "mypath/node_modules/@types/d3/index"'

Could you please help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Since EventDrop does not have a TypeScript implementation - afaik - and it builds on top of the d3 module, you should mock the missing properties - something like `interface d3{ chart: Function; }`. But to test if the imports work you could just `(<any>d3).chart.eventDrops();` or something like this. Again, only to test, **not the right way to do this** :)

Comment: Hi @mkaran, thank you very much!

I tried your quick test but then I got `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventDrops' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventDrops' of undefined`. Then I wanted to try **eventDrops** alone by adding:

`console.log(eventDrops);`

but then at runtime the execution failed because it does not find d3, despite I imported it in my component:

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
ReferenceError: d3 is not defined`.

Do you have any idea about how to make d3 visible to eventDrops?

Comment: Hmm, are you using angular cli? If yes, have you included the "../node_modules/event-drops/dist/eventDrops.js" to `angular-cli.json` in the scripts section?

Comment: I don't think I am using the angular cli. I started from an online example you can find [here](https://github.com/CRANK211/vs17-ng2-dnc/tree/master/4%20-%20completed-sample).

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments I finally got it working but note that it is a workaround. Event drops *hooks* to the global d3 variable, not the declared import from the 'd3' module.
So, you can use eventsDrop as in your example by using the `window.d3.chart.eventsDrop(...)` like this:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component} from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as eventDrops from 'event-drops';

declare global {
    interface Window { d3: any; }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'some-selector',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.css']
})
export class SomeComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(d3, eventDrops, window.d3.chart.eventDrops)
    // or use window['d3'].chart.eventsDrop
    // or any of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript
     var eventDropsChart = window.d3.chart.eventDrops();
  }

}
```

Hope this helps! Good luck!

I'll update the answer if I find a more sane and elegant way to do this!

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I'm going to try this workaround as soon as possible and let you know! :)

I really appreciate your big big big help!

Comment: It's not working for me:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
    at Object.defineProperty.value (eventDrops.js:1)
    at e (eventDrops.js:1)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (eventDrops.js:1)
    at e (eventDrops.js:1)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (eventDrops.js:1)
    at eventDrops.js:1
    at r (eventDrops.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (eventDrops.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f9901e4…:657)
    at fn (bootstrap f9901e4…:85)`

I tried to split, `console.log(d3)` alone is ok, but if I add `console.log(eventDrops)` I get the same error.
Any typo?

Comment: @Brutus hmm I'll look it up, it might have to do with the order the scripts are loaded or something else I am missing right now. Btw did you try with `ngAfterViewInit` ?

Comment: Yes, I used ngAfterViewInit. I will try to upload my solution to GitHub asap, it may be useful to share the same "environment".

Comment: @Brutus yes that would help a lot! let me know!

Comment: I just pushed my solution to [GitHub](https://github.com/ptagl/EventDrops-on-Angular-4) in order to make it easier to solve the issue. The project contains 2 branches: the master contains the solution proposed by you, the "porkaround" contains a very ugly workaround I found (importing D3.js as a script instead as a NPM package).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but if anyone runs into this I was able to get it working by assigning global in polyfills.ts. Then you can use it just like the event-drops instructions describe for a Module Bundler:

```
(window as any).global = window;
```