# TypeScript error TS2339: Property 'app' does not exist on type 'Window'

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I try start use TypeScript 2.4.1 on my old AngularJS project. Firstly I try to refactor my simple controller to ts. On controller, I use anonymous function in compile process get `Error:(35, 11) TS2339:Property 'app' does not exist on type 'Window'.`

```
  (function (app) {
    'use strict';
    app.ReservationModule.controller('ItineraryController', ItineraryController);

    ItineraryController.$inject = [
        'SeatMapService',
        'SeatMapSegments'
    ];

    /**
     *  Controlling interaction between seatMap service and Itinerary view.
     */
    function ItineraryController(SeatMapService:any, SeatMapSegments:any) {

        const vm = this;
        vm.deselectService = deselectService;
        vm.show = show;

        /**
         * Deselect traveller seat on seatMap service by segment.
         */
        function deselectService(traveller, segment) {
            SeatMapService.deselectService(traveller, segment);
        }

        /**
         * Returns true if segment has new seatMap service.
         * @param segment
         * @return {boolean}
         */
        function show(segment) {
            return SeatMapSegments.getSegment(segment).hasNewSeatsService();
        }
    }
})(window.app); // type script error reason is here
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make window dynamic.

`(<any>window).app`

You can also reference this question:
[How do you explicitly set a new property on `window` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

Comment: Seems like you just copied someone else's answer. If you think the two questions are the same, then vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Seems like I answered the question and referenced another question.  Calling me down won't help this guy. My answer will.

Comment: And your whole thing of copying an answer is ridiculous. I already knew the answer and found the post that I learned it from (and that I had already upvoted) and linked it.  EVERY answer is copied from somewhere, even if it's the doc, and I don't see people getting downvoted for those.