# Extending global types (e.g. "Window") inside a typescript module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

If you are writing in typescript, and are not using modules, it is possible to extend the global `Window` object. For example, this compiles:

```
interface Window {
    myCounter: number;
}

window.myCounter = window.myCounter || 0;
++window.myCounter;

function outputLoadingDetails() {
    console.log(`myCounter= ${window.myCounter}`)
}
```

But if I prefix the function `outputLoadingDetails` with `export`, it appears I am converting this file into a module. I now get a compiler error when I access `window.myCounter`.

```
interface Window {
    myCounter: number;
}

window.myCounter = window.myCounter || 0; // ERROR: property 'MyCounter' does not exist on type `Window`
++window.myCounter;                       // ERROR: property 'MyCounter' does not exist on type `Window`

export function outputLoadingDetails() {
    console.log(`myCounter= ${window.myCounter}`)  // ERROR: property 'MyCounter' does not exist on type `Window`
}
```

It appears my interface declaration is no longer extending the global `Window` type.

One workaround I've found is to put the interface declaration into a separate `*.d.ts` file, and reference this from my module.

But now I'm curious. Is there some way I can extend the `Window` interface within the module code?

Comment: How do you reference the d.ts file from you module in your workaround ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you explicitly set a new property on \`window\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yes, you just need to wrap the interface into global declaration:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        myCounter: number;
    }
}
```

> Global scope can be augmented from modules using a `declare global` declarations

More info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html#augmenting-globalmodule-scope-from-modules)

---

** Make sure the file is treated as a module (has `import` or `export` statement, if not - you can add empty `export {}`)

Comment: For anyone being and wondering why your `.d.ts` file not working: add `export {}` to your file if there is no export in the file. This makes TS recognize your file as a module. Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html#example-6

Comment: This is the correct way of passing data from server context to browser context while using typescript

Comment: if we just have a ambient declaration in d.ts and not add an export to treat it as a module, would this not work ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 Then you probably don't need `declare global` wrapper https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOqgCYHsDuyDeAUMicgLYCeAwlgK7jQBcyItZARtANyEC+hhHJlwA6SjXqQoyALzIAjACYAzFyA

Answer (score 26):

I didn't like modifying the `global` declaration as modifications would appear in other files.

This was my solution:

```js
interface customWindow extends Window {
  customProperty?: any;
}

declare const window: customWindow;

/* ... */

window.customProperty
```

Comment: Much better when you need specific properties on specific files.