# How to check if an object is a readonly array in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typechecking

How to do an array check (like `Array.isArray()`) with a readonly array (`ReadonlyArray`)?

As an example:

```js
type ReadonlyArrayTest = ReadonlyArray<string> | string | undefined;

let readonlyArrayTest: ReadonlyArrayTest;

if (readonlyArrayTest && !Array.isArray(readonlyArrayTest)) {
  // Here I expect `readonlyArrayTest` to be a string
  // but the TypeScript compiler thinks it's following:
  // let readonlyArrayTest: string | readonly string[]
}
```

With an usual array the TypeScript compiler correctly recognises that it must be a string inside the if condition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here's](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17002) relevant issue in typescript.

Suggested workaround by [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) is adding overload to declaration of `isArray`:

```
declare global {
    interface ArrayConstructor {
        isArray(arg: ReadonlyArray<any> | any): arg is ReadonlyArray<any>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but where should I put that interface declaration? It's not working if I just paste it into the file where the issue appears.

Comment: @mamiu inside module you'll need to wrap this in "global declaration". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47130406/extending-window-inside-a-typescript-module/47130953#47130953

Comment: Amazing! Posted this answer on the Github issue.

Comment: Should really be `arg is ReadonlyArray<any> | any[]`, since arg might not be a ReadonlyArray.

Comment: @AlekseyL. `ReadonlyArray<any> | Readonly<any>`  to not overriding default declaration

Answer (score 2):

it should be like this

```
interface ArrayConstructor {
  isArray(arg: unknown): arg is unknown[] | readonly unknown[];
}
```

and test it in typescript

```
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
if (Array.isArray(a)) {
  console.log(a); // a is string[]
} else {
  console.log(a); // a is never
}

const b: readonly string[] = ['1', '2', '3']

if (Array.isArray(b)) {
  console.log(b); // b is readonly string[]
} else {
  console.log(b); // b is never
}

function c(val: string | string[]) {
  if (Array.isArray(val)) {
    console.log(val); // val is string[]
  }
  else {
    console.log(val); // val is string
  }
}

function d(val: string | readonly string[]) {
  if (Array.isArray(val)) {
    console.log(val); // val is readonly string[]
  }
  else {
    console.log(val); // val is string
  }
}

function e(val: string | string[] | readonly string[]) {
  if (Array.isArray(val)) {
    console.log(val); // val is string[] | readonly string[]
  }
  else {
    console.log(val); // val is string
  }
}
```