# Array.isArray check not sufficient to quite compiler about possible array value in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In a method, I have a type with a possible value of an array. However, before I access the argument, I check to ensure that the argument isn't an array.

I still get the following error (excerpt) on line `this.setState({ cuisine });`:

`Type 'readonly SelectOption[]' is missing the following properties from type 'SelectOption': value, label`

When I hover over `cuisine` on the error line, the type determined by VS Code is `SelectOption | readonly SelectOption[]`

Here's the code:

```
interface SelectOption {
  value: number | string;
  label: string
}

private onCuisineChange(cuisine: ValueType<SelectOption>): void {
    if (Array.isArray(cuisine) && cuisine.length > 1)  {
        throw new Error(`Expected cuisine to be an object, but got ${cuisine}`);
    }

    if (cuisine) {
        this.setState({ cuisine });
    } else {

    }
}
```

Using TS version 3.5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript is correctly inferring the type here. In addition to the array check, there is the condition `&& cuisine.length > 1`. This means that the exception is only thrown if `cuisine` is an array **with more than one element in it**.

The lower `if` statement could still be executed where `cuisine` is an empty array or array with a single element hence the type `SelectOption | readonly SelectOption[]`.

With that being said, as of 3.5.1, [TypeScript#17002](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17002) (thanks @SeanVieira) is still open about `Array.isArray` not narrowing `readonly` arrays. A workaround provided there is to include, somewhere in your project's declarations, an overload to tell typescript that it should in fact narrow `readonly` arrays as well:

> From https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249765/10609635
>
> ```
> declare global {
>     interface ArrayConstructor {
>         isArray(arg: ReadonlyArray<any> | any): arg is ReadonlyArray<any>
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: There is an interesting problem in that even without the extra check, `Array.isArray` is not enough to narrow the type.  This also looks like a genuine bug with TS, since adding `interface ArrayConstructor { isArray(value: any): value is readonly any[]; }` resolves the second issue.

Comment: I did have just an `Array.isArray` check as well and get the same error. Thanks for the issue link, @SeanVieira. I did a quick search but failed to find it.

Comment: Yes @SeanVieira, the link is much appreciated. Let me collect some of that and put it into the answer.