# Why type inference is lost when using Array.isArray?

Tags: typescript

I'm just wondering why the type inference for the intellisense gets lost inside an `Array.isArray` condition.

Consider the following snippet:

```
type T = {
    readonly name: string;
    readonly descr: string;
}

interface I{
    readonly tags: ReadonlyArray<T>;
}

function Z(arg: I): void{
    const { tags } = arg;
    if (Array.isArray(tags)) {  //hovering "tags" here shows "readonly T[]"
        for (let t of tags) {   //hovering "tags" here shows "any[]"

        }
    }
}

Z({
    tags:[]
})
```

In other words, why the original type is not preserved from its declaration, and changes getting the `isArray` signature instead?

Tested on Visual Studio, and also in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17002) with `ReadonlyArray` and the type guard function `Array.isArray`. You can also find a possible fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249765/5669456).

> In other words, why the original type is not preserved from its declaration, and changes getting the isArray signature instead?

Part of the reason is, that `Array<any>` actually is a *sub-type* of `ReadonlyArray<any>`.

```
type IsArraySubtypeOfROArray = Array<any> extends ReadonlyArray<any> ? true : false // true
type IsROArraySubtypeOfArray = ReadonlyArray<any> extends Array<any> ? true : false // false
```

As Maciej says in his answer, there is no check necessary, as you can already be sure to have an array in above case. So let's assume property `tags` has type `T | ReadonlyArray<T>` to make it more interesting.

With the built-in `ArrayConstructor` interface

```
interface ArrayConstructor {
  ...
  isArray(arg: any): arg is any[];
}
```

and given `Array.isArray(tags)` returns `true`, the compiler compares type `T | ReadonlyArray<T>` from `tags` with type `any[]` from `isArray` return type. Neither `T` nor `ReadonlyArray<T>` are a sub type of `any[]`. So the compiler looks the other way round, if `any[]` is a sub-type of `T` or `ReadonlyArray<T>`. As that is the case with `ReadonlyArray<T>`, control flow analysis now resolves to `any[]` as the most narrow type possible.

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEEUFcFMGcBcCWB7AdqAxgQ1tANKAA4BOyh0xANgJ6jzXkAmoA7ovABagCCxxW1AMJoExSBnjJioLJADmAW2ip4WJGgBQGxCooAzLBmg8+A4alHjJ0gN4bQD0Ili9+1ABRZicgFwzU1ACUfl5yTrCgAErQWIxoNK4CADxYAQB8jqAaAL5a9OSgACqgALygdpnEMXGoNKCoWEp+ojpyANz2jlWx8bSMcBjEzfDErR252rrEBkagAJIVXdW9dFhysH7RPbXUidRJhWnjWnqQqBIo6ABant5+c8GgAG7IiIyLDhgi8OWr66DZUoybwdTKIPSgdx7AB0zj27lU60CgV+WUymURERADgAcsgWARMaAANbQaCECLdGp1QoAbQAunQGNBoZ10aA9FJIZRoD8fsgIZiUTYAWzRRMbh8-hsGTlAloNNj8sY5JAvMwGnx8a1QNAAB6NQg82BafoYSheYxfCw-LxDeqQBQAIwoDNAAB9QC1UHI3RozRaqhyzhc0OEAMojVrwrAhAKPLDhL1Rn2y7QQ9zOSOjH0xvjI8piu2gbF24Y5330sXY5MVt16UgKCMpuR7UAKKTGWDkDDgxAYOgcVK11puz2oR0u4j1xvA4g5U3Qc2WzDfEe5vjl0dVgMr07ndToLMtgDyxBxk4oMbjQRCSe9lY9Dudrqr6chx4rZ4vL+I8IfrgFlKAF8CWYAgfaD6ypkNZQYyDbIE2EHtp2Xo9n2A6cMOcFPhOv4zohzZfuel5-qY1ALkAA) with a properly typed example.

Comment: I moved the best answer here. As said, my real code is much more complex than the snippet, and I can't rely on a simple declaration because the data comes from another source (that is, the field may be even undefined). I typically use isArray when I have an optional parameter which expects an array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
Array.isArray(tags)
```

This type guard if passed is stating that you work with `any[]`. This is quite understandable us if you checking if something is an array. This guard doesnt check the element, and it is hard to check as array can be empty. The standard case of using `Array.isArray` is situation where you don't know what you got (like union type where value can or can be not an array), and you want to ensure that it is an array. Next thing is to check array of what.

Your example is quite unusual as there is no need for check, as you have statically set that you get `T[]` as an input. So for type system `Array.isArray(tags)` has no sense as `tags` are known to be an array of T.

You can fix this behavior by custom type guard:

```
const isArray = <V>(a: any): a is V[] => Array.isArray(a);
// above guard set additional type information to the array element

// usage
if (isArray<T>(tags)) {  //hovering "tags" here shows "readonly T[]"
        tags // here tags are T[]
    }
```

But in your example this has no sense until the input will be something less specific then just `T[]`, for example it would have sense for input like `T | T[]`:

```
interface I{
    readonly tags: ReadonlyArray<T> | T; // union type
}
```

Then checking has a sense as we have branching here to deal differently with `T[]` and `T`.

Comment: My example is a cut of a larger piece of code. The "tags" field is yes part of an interface, but the actual object could come from "anywhere", hence no guarantee that it'll be an array. However, if it is an array, it is made of *that* T. Thank you, anyway: I missed this perspective.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I find the ford04 answer more exaustive, thus I've given him the reward. I thank you again for your noticeable explaination.