# No declarations written for TypeScript file that exports nothing

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser

I'm currently writing my code in TypeScript, and I'm not using a library like Webpack to bundle the code. I've set the [`declaration`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declaration) flag to `true` in my `tsconfig.json` to ask TypeScript to generate declarations for the code. I'm making a class accessible on the `window` object for external scripts to make use of, and I'm currently doing so with the following code (`Foo.ts`):

```js
(() => {
    class Foo {
        // ...
    }

    (window as any).Foo = Foo;
})();
```

When transpiled into JavaScript, this works and the Foo class can be found on the `window` object. However, the declaration file (`Foo.d.ts`) contains nothing.

I assumed that this was because the file wasn't exporting anything, so I changed the code to export the variable (and place it in the top-level rather than in a closure) and it worked. However, specific to my use case, it made no sense to "export" a variable when the script is going to be loaded in the browser (of course, unless I used something like Webpack).

This is so far preventing me referencing the class type in integration tests. I can't simply `declare` the variable for use either since it would require writing my own `d.ts` file (which defeats the purpose of just using TypeScript) nor can I declare it midway through my existing `Foo.ts` file since TypeScript does not allow non-top-level `declare`s. It wouldn't make sense for me to add in Webpack to the toolchain and add more bloat to a small script that doesn't use any dependencies either.

I've actually run into this same issue trying to get types for [`oojs-ui`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oojs-ui), which does the same thing. Unfortunately, I'm not as keen to simply set `window.Foo` to `any` in my tests and hope for the best.

How can I have TypeScript emit the declaration for the `Foo` class, without needing an `export` statement? In other words, how can I have TypeScript export declarations for a class appended to the `window` variable?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you're missing is module augmentation in the global namespace. If you add your class definition in the way [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47130953/10345775) does it resolve your issue?

Something like [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DEITgbwCg4S4wBXAIyQEsFEIA7NGKchGaACgurrkoooALjgsoNRgHMAlAQC+hRYQAmwZEOBwpSCIKQFipSTGBQAZigRaA6pJUQA7odKvsuUTACeYYBHPuEADcRiSKio72TgB0OHgAvIEhhIzAzpGMDo6xuFwA5AgoMHkyQUA)

Comment: This does mean that I have to take the class out of the closure (since ambient declarations must be top-level), but I guess I can live with that.