How to write d.ts file to let tsc know, that the window object is extended
we have a javascript project and want to move to typescript.
In the current setup, we have a global object (let's call it myGlobal) with variables and functions that we are accessing either through windows.myGlobal.myFunction or directly as myGlobal.varA.
As expected, tsc would complain that windows.myGlobal does not exist on the window object.
My guess was to write a global.d.ts declaration file for tsc like this:
interface myGlobal {
  myFunction: any
}


// Extend the Window interface
interface Window {
  myGlobal: MyGlobal;
}

// Declare myGlobal as a global variable
declare let myGlobal: MyGlobal;

and even though I have
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.js"
  ],

in my tsconfig, it still complaints about the same error.
Can someone help?

Can you share the error message you are getting?

I have found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47130406/extending-global-types-e-g-window-inside-a-typescript-module and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074713/extending-typescript-global-object-in-node-js

Here's my code example

You can see that typescript picks up the global variables. I've put my d.ts file in the root of the project.
A better approach to do this is to use a singleton class or static properties in a Global class
class Globals {
  static myGlobalVar: string = "Hello, World!";
}


How come this is a better approach?

@evolutionxbox
This really is a question for ChatGPT. It can lead to potential for code conflicts, poor state management, worst debugging nightmare issues to name a few
Mostly depends on the use case and how you are using the global items
