# Typescript: Add functions to "window" with ".d.ts" File

Tags: typescript

I'm having a legacy *.js application and want to port parts of it to typescript.

So far I found @types definitions for most of the used packages, but there is a global function added to the window object.

I was able to fix the compilation error by addind this at the beginning of the *.ts File:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        openConformationModal?: any;
    }
}
```

Now obv I don't want to include this in all my *.ts so I wanted to added it to a *.d.ts file so it is recogniced in all packages.

The problem is, that if I add the same file to a e.g. window.d.ts file, it isn't recogniced. I know that the types in the folder are found because I a added it with

```
 {
  ...,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ....
    "typeRoots": [
      "FFOLDERPATH_TO_D_TS_FILE"
    ]
  }
}
```

and there is another *.d.ts which is found.

PS: Solution is based on [How do you explicitly set a new property on `window` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it further down this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40698148

```
interface Window {
  MyNamespace: any;
}
```

> Full answer:

Here's how to do it, if you're using [TypeScript Definition Manager](https://github.com/typings/typings)*!*

```
npm install typings --global
```

Create `typings/custom/window.d.ts`:

```
interface Window {
  MyNamespace: any;
}

declare var window: Window;
```

Install your custom typing:

```
typings install file:typings/custom/window.d.ts --save --global
```

Done, use it‌*!* Typescript won't complain anymore:

```
window.MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};
```

Comment: This is the perfect usecase for `npx` as in `npx typings install file:typings/custom/window.d.ts --save --global` so you don't have to install and maintain version of the typings library locally

Comment: Typescript Definition Manager has been deprecated. Any updates to the answer?