# Accessing External Javascript Lib in React Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app which the components are controlled by a Store.ts file.

I followed some steps in other threads here on Stack Overflow. I've already included the script tag in my `index.html` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stc.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.directpayment.js"></script>
```

Then, as stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript), in my Store, before using one of the functions, I declared the library as part of `window` as follow:

```
declare global {
  interface Window { PagSeguroDirectPayment: any; }
}

window.PagSeguroDirectPayment = window.PagSeguroDirectPayment || {};

window.PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId('620f99e348c24f07877c927b353e49d3');
```

But when I run the app I get the error `window.PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId is not a function`. And when I call the function directly in the `index.html` it seems to work.

Am I declaring it in the wrong place or in the wrong way? 
I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: <script> should be loaded before this part of React app is being executed. The moment `window.PagSeguroDirectPayment` appears depends on how the script works, this may happen asynchronously. `window.PagSeguroDirectPayment = window.PagSeguroDirectPayment || {}` doesn't make much sense since it needs to have methods (setSessionId) any way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @estus. I just realized that I included the <script> in the body instead of in the header.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use globally declared elements with the window prefix.

E.g: `window.PagSeguroDirectPayment`

**Note:**
But without instructions like:

```
window.PagSeguroDirectPayment = window.PagSeguroDirectPayment || {}
```

because `window.PagSeguroDirectPayment` features are required.

Maybe that can help.