# Declare global for updating Window does not work

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following hierarchy

```
/
  /definitions
     window.d.ts
  /components
  ...
  tsconfig.json
```

With my `window.d.ts` being

```
export {}

declare global {
  interface Window { otherKey: any; }
}
```

And my `tsconfig.json` being

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "window": ["definitions/window.d.ts"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./App.tsx"
  ]
}
```

When I run dev-server, I get

```
[at-loader] Using typescript@2.6.1 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from /correct/path/tp/tsconfig.json.
```

But when webpack finishes, I get

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./component/SomeApp.tsx:78:35
    TS2339: Property 'otherKey' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

I have simply used `window.otherKey` without any other `declare var window: any` hoping that `otherKey` would just exist.

Why is this not working?

**EDIT**

I noticed this only happens for `.tsx` files. `.ts` files work fine ...

Comment: Are you importing `window.d.ts` in `SomeApp.tsx`?  Depending on your webpack configuration, that may help.

Comment: I am not; I use `window` in many files, and I don't want to consistently re-import it. I want it to be part of the path. If I do import it, then yes it will work,

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript):

```
declare global {
    interface Window { otherKey: any; }
}

window.otherKey= window.otherKey|| {};
```

Comment: That's just initializing it though; that has nothing to do with type definition