# Declaring the root global object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In a project I have several type declarations of global variables, like so:

```
declare const process: { [key: string]: any };
declare function setTimeout(...);
...
```

I am looking to declare a variable named "global" that refers to the global object (`global` in CommonJS) whose type is implied by all of the other global declarations in the project.

```
declare const global: ???
```

Specifically, I'd like for TypeScript to infer that `global.process` is an object and `global.setTimeout` is a function because those global variables are declared to be of those types.

Is there a way to get the type of the global object in TypeScript?

Comment: Take a look how it´s done here for the window object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12709880/5291195

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way for Typescript to infer it. If you're looking for specific members in global and know their types you can do it "manually". For example:

```
declare const global: {
    process: object, 
    setTimeout: (callback:(args:any[])=>void, duration:number)
};
```