# Creating global javascript object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

In my Angular6 component, I am embedding an iframe. 
The javascript code inside the iframe needed me to declare a global object with a specific name ("API Callback") so that it can invoke different methods on the global object. Is it possible to create a global object like this as we used to do in JavaScript?

Comment: I think a global scope is one for the component. And if you want to make a scope that is the same over multiple you can put it in a shared service.

Comment: Service wont work for me. The third party code which I embed in iframe needs me to create a global variable with few functions implemented.

Comment: Is the code within I frame in your control?

Comment: No, I cant change the code in iframe.

Comment: Why don't you create an object in window object.. in your app component?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a global object, then just attach it to the `window` object.

```js
window.property = `I'm global`;

console.log(property);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am using Angular6, so the below code worked for me. Got it from (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13480754/5841523)     

window['propertyName'] = MyTypeScriptCallbackObject;

Comment: you mean Typescript complained about the `window.property` syntax?