# Error with Redux DevTools Extension using TS: "Property '__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__' does not exist on type 'Window'."?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-devtools-extension

I'm getting this error on my index.tsx.

Property '**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE**' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Here is my index.tsx code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers';

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

 const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(
     applyMiddleware(thunk)
 ));

ReactDOM.render(  <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

I've installed @types/npm install --save-dev redux-devtools-extension and I'm using create-react-app-typescript. Thanks alot for any tips for what's going on in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is how you can use `redux-dev-tools` in a typescript react application.

#### Create global Interface for the `Window` object:

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__?: typeof compose;
  }
}
```

#### Then, create `composeEnhancers` as follows:

```js
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
```

#### Then create a `store`.

```js
const store = createStore(rootReducers, composeEnhancers());
```

**`rootReducers`** - in my case refers to `combinedReducers` created in a surparate file.

Now you can use `Provider` as usual in `React.js` as:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

#### All the code in the `index.tsx`

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import rootReducers from "./reducers";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__?: typeof compose;
  }
}

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(rootReducers, composeEnhancers());

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Getting a suggestion: We recommend using the configureStore method of the @reduxjs/toolkit package, which replaces createStore.

Redux Toolkit is our recommended approach for writing Redux logic today, including store setup, reducers, data fetching, and more.

configureStore from Redux Toolkit is an improved version of createStore that simplifies setup and helps avoid common bugs.

Answer (score 124):

This is a special case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript). Redux doesn't provide types for `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` because this function is exposed by Redux DevTools, not Redux itself.

It's either:

```
const composeEnhancers = window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__'] as typeof compose || compose;
```

Or:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
      __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__?: typeof compose;
    }
}

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
```

This is already done by [`@redux-devtools/extension`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@redux-devtools/extension) package that contains TypeScript typings. If it's installed, its imports should be used instead of accessing `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` manually.

Comment: Thanks so much for this @etus, you're a life savor!!

Comment: Using `window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__']` I get an error saying that window uses numeric index while we set a string...

Comment: @Peppe The problem is likely specific to your setup, old TS version or messed up typings. You can try `(window as any)['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__']` as a dirty fix. Any way,  redux-devtools-extension is a good way to solve this.

Comment: I am facing an issue saying unexpected token at declare global

Answer (score 36):

The most streamlined way to make this work with `TypeScript` is to use the [redux-devtools-extension](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-devtools-extension) and install as a dev dependency as follows:

```
npm install --save-dev redux-devtools-extension
```

The next step for those new to `redux` and these developer tools was confusing and unclear. The docs all have code like the following:

```
const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  // other store enhancers if any
));
```

The problem is I don't have any middleware configured so this wasn't working. In it's most primitive usage, this is all you need:

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const store = createStore(myReducer, composeWithDevTools());
```

At this point if you click the extension in the browser and there is a valid redux store, you will be able to inspect the state.

This is an alternative approach to using `(window as any)` and also clears up just exaclty *how* to use the `redux-devtools-extension` in its minimal form.

Comment: I think this solution using **redux-devtools-extension** from npm is the cleaner one. I used it and works great.

Comment: Not to add noise, but this looks much more proper and should be accepted as the answer (especially since the OP didn't state they can't import `composeWithDevTools` for whatever reason). And we don't have to add more `as any`'s!

Answer (score 22):

My approach to the issue was the following:

```
export const composeEnhancers =
  (window && (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) || compose;
```

Comment: But what if you can't use `any` as a type?

Answer (score 11):

Working as a charm:

```
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),
        (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )       

);
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue too however, I'm also using redux-thunk as a middleware. Running

```
npm install --save-dev redux-devtools-extension
```

and then adding in

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
```

to index.tsx did the trick for me, as well as updating the store to

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
```

My full index.tsx is below. Hopefully this will help anyone with the same issue that is using middleware such as redux-thunk

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './containers/App/App'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import authReducer from './store/reducers/auth'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer
})
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'))

serviceWorker.unregister()
```

Answer (score 3):

if any one still stuck into this issue I fixed it and this is my final store.js file
with following packages
1- Redux Thunk
2- Connected React Router 
3- History

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';
import rootReducer from '../redux/reducers';
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
const initialState = {}
const enhancers = []
const middleware = [
    thunk,
    routerMiddleware(history)
]

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const devToolsExtension = (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() || compose;
    if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
        enhancers.push(devToolsExtension)
    }
}

const composedEnhancers = compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    ...enhancers
);

export default createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composedEnhancers
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue changed I just changed

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```

to

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__() || compose
```

to get past an `undefined` apply issue when using `createStore(reducer, initial state, compose(applyMiddleware`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with getting concurrently to work, the general advice I found is to replace your "client" script in package.json with: 
 "client": "cd client && npm start",

I tried this and I still got an error, so then I tried: 
 "client": "cd client && cd my-app && npm start",

This worked for me! The problem is that when you use create-react-app inside the "client" folder, there is an added level in between the client folder and your public and src folders which is called "my-app" by default. Using Brad's code, npm misses this folder so can't find the react files it needs to start your app.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have used `react-redux-devtools`. Try this solution may be it will help you to resolve your issue.

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import { rootReducer } from "../reducers";
import { AppState } from "@eneto/api-client";

import { initUserState } from "../../modules/users/user-reducer";
import { initUsersState } from "../../modules/users/users-reducer";
import { initListsState } from "../../modules/lists/lists-reducer";
import { initListState } from "../../modules/lists/list-reducer";

// initialValues
const init: AppState = {
    currentUser: initUserState,
    users: initUsersState,
    lists: initListsState,
    currentList: initListState
};

export function store(initialState: AppState = init) {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    const middleware = [sagaMiddleware];

    return {
        ...createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))),
        runSaga: sagaMiddleware.run
    };
}
```

#reactjs