# MathJax in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, mathjax

Unfortunately, very little information on this library. It is not completely clear to me after installation what I need to import into the **app.module.ts** and whether there is something to import there? I have prescribed the following code in the index.html:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]
  }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
 src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js? 
 config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML'>
</script>
```

And how can I apply the MathJax, if I have not simple text, but a table in which text with formulas appears in some columns? Perhaps you can somehow transfer the entire table to MathJax.Hub.Queue?

Comment: did you reference this link http://embed.plnkr.co/qBRAIxR27zK3bpo6QipY/

Comment: yes, but this is old code and it could change

Comment: This might be helpful for users trying to implement on Angular 17: https://medium.com/@vanyamyshkin/latex-with-mathjax-3-in-angular-17-4b66d95300ad

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was looking at the same problem like two weeks ago and today i finally manage to make it work. I'm no angular expert so it may need some optimization, but core funcionality is working.

#### Step one

Add `@types/mathjax` dependency to your `package.json` file.

#### Step two

Add newly added type to `tsconfig.app.json` like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["mathjax"]
  }
}
```

This will allow you to use constructs such as `MathJax.Callback.Queue` and your IDE won't complain about unkown type etc.

#### Step three create wrapper object for your math content (optional)

I had some issues with Mathml so i have created wrapper for math which looks like this :

```js
export interface MathContent {
  latex?: string;
  mathml?: string;
}
```

#### Step four

Now we need to define module which whill inject MathJax script tag with configuration. Because it will be loaded dynamically `async` we need to make sure typesetting doesn't start before MathJax is fully loaded. Easiest way is to store `Observer<any>` into `window` object. `Observer` and render functionality can be wrapped into service.

```js
// see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12709880/1203690
declare global {
  interface Window {
    hubReady: Observer<boolean>;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class MathServiceImpl {
  private readonly notifier: ReplaySubject<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.notifier = new ReplaySubject<boolean>();
    window.hubReady = this.notifier; // as said, bind to window object
  }

  ready(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.notifier;
  }

  render(element: HTMLElement, math?: MathContent): void {
    if (math) {
      if (math.latex) {
        element.innerText = math.latex;
      } else {
        element.innerHTML = math.mathml;
      }
    }

    MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, element]);
  }
}
```

#### Step five

Now we will create directive which will trigger rendering once MathJax is loaded. The directive may look like this:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMath]'
})
export class MathDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  private alive$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  @Input()
  private appMath: MathContent;
  private readonly _el: HTMLElement;

  constructor(private service: MathServiceImpl,
              private el: ElementRef) {
    this._el = el.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service
      .ready()
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        takeUntil(this.alive$)
      ).subscribe(res => {
        this.service.render(this._el, this.appMath);
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.alive$.next(false);
  }
}
```

#### Step six (almost there)

In step four i mentioned `async` loading. According to docs on[MathJax](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/dynamic.html) this is done using `document.createElement`. Angular Module is perfect place for this logic. To trigger `.ready()` method on our `MathService` we will use `MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook` and pass observable from `MathService` So our module will look like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MathDirective],
  exports: [MathDirective]
})
export class MathModule {
  constructor(mathService: MathServiceImpl) {
    // see https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/dynamic.html
    const script = document.createElement('script') as HTMLScriptElement;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML';
    script.async = true;

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    const config = document.createElement('script') as HTMLScriptElement;
    config.type = 'text/x-mathjax-config';
    // register notifier to StartupHook and trigger .next() for all subscribers
    config.text = `
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        skipStartupTypeset: true,
        tex2jax: { inlineMath: [["$", "$"]],displayMath:[["$$", "$$"]] }
      });
      MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook('End', () => {
        window.hubReady.next();
        window.hubReady.complete();
      });
    `;

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(config);
  }

  // this is needed so service constructor which will bind
  // notifier to window object before module constructor is called
  public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MathModule,
      providers: [{provide: MathServiceImpl, useClass: MathServiceImpl}]
    };
  }
}
```

#### Step seven: render math

Now everything is ready simply import `MathModule.forRoot()` in module where you want to render math. The component will look like this:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  mathLatex: MathContent = {
    latex: 'When $a \\ne 0$, there are two solutions to $\\frac{5}{9}$'
  };

  mathMl: MathContent = {
    mathml: `<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mrow>
    <mover>
      <munder>
        <mo>∫</mo>
        <mn>0</mn>
      </munder>
      <mi>∞</mi>
    </mover>
    <mtext> versus </mtext>
    <munderover>
      <mo>∫</mo>
      <mn>0</mn>
      <mi>∞</mi>
    </munderover>
  </mrow>
</math>`
  };
}
```

and template

```html
<div [appMath]="mathLatex"></div>

<div [appMath]="mathMl"></div>

<!-- will render inline element math -->
<div [appMath]>
  $E = mc^2$
</div>
```

Which should render to this

[image]

#### Step eight (bonus)

Here is working stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/mathjax-example so you can check your progress against implementation

Comment: I hope this decision will help others.

for installation MathJax `npm install mathjax` and `npm install --save @types/mathjax`

Comment: No need for the `npm install mathjax` because the Mathjax is loaded by the create element and `npm install -D @types/mathjax` can be installed as Dev dependencies because to prevent it going into your prod bundle.

Comment: You are a life savior @emptak, Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you! I've tried a few angular wrapper, but this answer was the only that did the job

Comment: For development mode it's working fine. I am getting this error for prod ssr build for it. any help ? ` Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'MathModule' was called.'.

Comment: In MathJax v3 use `MathJax.typesetPromise()` rather than `MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, element])`, and replace `config.text` with `MathJax = { tex: { inlineMath: [["$", "$"]] }, startup: { ready: () => { MathJax.startup.defaultReady(); window.hubReady.next(); window.hubReady.complete(); } } }`, and `script.src` with https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js