# How to use MathJax in Nativescript - Angular

Tags: android, mathjax, nativescript-angular

I want to use `MathJax` in `Nativescript-Angular` in order to build an android app.

Actually I tried with some angular packages like `ngx-mathjax` and `ng-katex` but they are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using Angular 6+

There is similar discussion available on StackOverFlow which can be referred.
Hope this will help you.

[MathJax in Angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125544/mathjax-in-angular-6)

Comment: Yes , I am using angular 7

Comment: Ok, then please follow link provided in above comments