# How to write mathematical formula in angular?

Tags: angular

I would like to know a method to write a mathematical formula in angular. Specifically:

a) How to include non-English characters?
b) How to include multi-line text (above and below the 'divided by' symbol)

I came across MathML. However, there are a lot of markups involved to write a formula. I would like to know if there is an 'angular' way of handing mathematical formula?

I would like to visualise the formula in a webpage, and not execute it.

Comment: Use Typescript?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve? Do you want to visualize math formulas or execute math formulas? Where exactly do you get stuck? What formulas do you want to calculate/visualize?

Comment: Thank you @NatashaKurian. Can you tell me how to use typescript for this?

Comment: @RubenSzekér, I would like to visualise a mathematical formula, not execute it.

Comment: Thank you @RubenSzekér, I haved edited the question to include the word visualise.

Comment: You gave the answer yourself: There’s MathML to express a formular. And for non-English characters, you have the whole world of Unicode at your hands.

Comment: Thank you @lxg. I will use Unicode for the non-English characters. I found that MathML is not supported by many browsers (https://caniuse.com/mathml). Is MathML a good solution?

Comment: Well, then use either a polyfill (if it works good enough for your use case), or SVG or a PNG screenshot as alternative content. Come on, do some research on your own, you’re not the first person with this problem.

Comment: Are you looking for a Mathjax? take a look to this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125544/mathjax-in-angular-6 or this another link https://medium.com/kongsberg-digital/how-to-render-mathml-in-browser-using-angular-and-mathjax-3-along-with-lazy-loading-83f791911cfd

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo, the links are useful.