# Tslint Angular: Usage of window is not allowed

Tags: angular, tslint

I need to print one of the pages in my Angular app, so I have something like:

```
myPage = window.open();
myPage.Print();
```

The thing is that I get the following error from tslint:

"Usage of window is not allowed"

I looked of some answeres here / other solutions, for example: 
https://brianflove.com/2018/01/11/angular-window-provider/

but they all use at some point `window`

```
 return window;
```

and then I'll get the error messge `"Usage of window is not allowed"` again.

How can I solve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you explicitly set a new property on \`window\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I looked into these answers, but all of them at some point will have the window word. My tslint pretty much not allows the use of the word window. And I can't change the tslint file. Is there any other way to print the window without the window object? Or get a reference to window without the word window? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved it by instead of do `myPage = window.open();` , just do:

```
myPage = open();
```

instead ...

pretty much so easy.