# How to define browserHistory on the window object with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am new to typescript and am having a hard figuring out how to define `browserHistory` on the window object. I am using the [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) package from ReactTraining.

In my `app.jsx` I have:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: basePath,
});

window.browserHistory = history;
```

Then in my `modules.d.ts` I have this code which is not working:

```
import { History } from '@types/history';
interface Window { browserHistory: History; }
```

Anywhere is my app that I am using `window.browserHistory` I get the error:

```
TS2339: Property 'browserHistory' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

I can get this error to go away but replacing `History` with `any` but that seems like an incorrect approach. The npm package [@types/history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/history) doesn't seem to have a clear example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you explicitly set a new property on \`window\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

This was the proper syntax

```
import { History } from 'history';

declare global {
    interface Window { browserHistory: History; }
}
```