# TypeScript error: Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Window'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I have added TS to my React/Redux app.

I use `window` object in my app like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let FB = window.FB;
}
```

TS throws an error:

> TypeScript error: Property 'FB' does not exist on type 'Window'. TS2339

I want to fix the error.

#### 1 (doesn't work)

```
// Why doesn't this work? I have defined a type locally

type Window = {
  FB: any
}

componentDidMount() {
  let FB = window.FB;
}

// TypeScript error: Property 'FB' does not exist on type 'Window'. TS2339
```

#### 2 (fixes the error)

I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56402425/1114926

```
declare const window: any;

componentDidMount() {
  let FB = window.FB;
}
// No errors, works well
```

Why doesn't the first version work, but the second does, even though I do not specify FB property at all?

Comment: Do you use modules ? The answer differs a bit depeding on that

Comment: I use React components. All the behavior above is from React components. They may be called sort of **modules** because they incapsulate logic

Answer (score 484):

**Why does `declare const window: any;` work?**

Because you declare a local variable of type `any`. Having something of type `any` essentially turns off type checking for `window` so you can do anything with it. I really do not recommend this solution, it is a really bad one.

**Why doesn't `type Window = { FB: any }` work?**
You define a type `Window`. This type if defined in a module has nothing to do with the type of the global `window` object, it is just a type that happens to be called `Window` inside your module.

**The good solution**
To extend `window` you must extend the global `Window` interface. You can do this like this:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        FB:any;
    }
}

let FB = window.FB; // ok now
```

Note that this extension is going to be available in your whole project not just the file you define it in. Also if `FB` has definitions you might consider typing it a bit better (`FB: typeof import('FBOrWhateverModuleNameThisHas')`)

Comment: Your "good solution" doesn't compile."Property FB does not exist on type window & typeof globalThis"

Comment: @jtiscione yes it does https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitReturns=false#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4CgAmwDGAbAhlYOAc2wgCNdtEU5a4BLAOxmCgDNdNCB1JtCAO7U6IuADEAQgC5cjAJ4BuGnVRI4KFNmDxJcALxwBfQQDpJCuAHpLcCAGs4jQUA if your file is not a module, remove the declare global https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitReturns=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOqgCYHsDuyDeAUMsgGIBCAXHCAJ4DchAvoQDYRhnnIC8yOmXADoK9ZAHpxyLAGtkIXEA

Comment: Why is this answer not marked as the Answer? I looked long and far to find a method to access reactive state functions from the console/external JS and this is the only one that compiled in TS and worked

Comment: @Beerswiller Because the OP couldn't get it to work and didn't bother to follow up ‍♂️

Comment: If admins cared about the quality of the content on this site, they would take over this derelict question and accept an answer.

Comment: This doesn't work: Top-level declarations in .d.ts files must start with either a 'declare' or 'export' modifier.

Comment: If anyone is struggling with this answer on angular, put this code ```declare global {
    interface Window {
        FB:any;
    }
}``` inside main.ts

Comment: @Luiz Can anyone correct this code

Comment: @VarunSharma is the same code of the answer, but  without the let FB = window.FB part

Comment: Putting it inside the main entry "main.ts" make it work, but why? why having it inside a global.d.ts doesn't work?

Comment: ok, I figure it out, you need to put `export {};` in the `*.d.ts` file in order for the compiler to read it.

Comment: If anyone is doing this with Typescript, this link may help you.
https://www.devextent.com/create-service-worker-typescript/

Answer (score 87):

There are a few ways to solve this problem.

Some examples:

1-) Do a cast

```js
(window as any).X
```

2-) Put the following code in a file named `react-app-env.d.ts`

```js
interface Window {
  X?: {
    Y?: {
      .......
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: W̶i̶n̶d̶o̶w̶s̶  (window as any).X

Comment: In case of Vite - vite-env.d.ts file

Answer (score 31):

you can solve the problem easily **without any need to declaration**

```
window["FB"]
```

**UPDATE** 
since it's a workaround without any compiler configuration to ensure your program's compatibility with typescript maybe you will need just a type validation.

```js
if(window["FB"]) {
  // do some FB logic
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, it says `TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.`

Comment: @shamaseen this is the fastest way to solve the problem if you have specific type for index, you can use Titian's solution

Comment: If you get the `TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'` message, the following `tsconfig.json` property/value can be used to suppress it: 
`"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true`

Comment: Don't suppress errors. The point of TypeScript is to catch errors like this.

Comment: @A-Diddy You know the easiest way to suppress errors in Typescript is to use Javascript, right?  If you're going to silence errors, why use Typescript? It's not like a truly static language where making the compile errors disappear is the same thing as fixing them. All you're doing is saying "I know better than you TS, shut up". But the whole reason for using Typescript is because most of us have learned, we usually don't know better than the compiler, at least not as the project grows or time passes on, and once you've silenced all the warnings, it's just JS or maybe even worse.

Answer (score 15):

I use this without declare global

```js
declare const window: Window &
   typeof globalThis & {
     FB: any
   }
```

Comment: There is a bracket too much... removing it I get `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'window'`

Comment: I did this too.

Answer (score 14):

Solution for the problem "Property does not exist on type Window in TypeScript":

STEP:1   In your src directory, create a types directory that contains the following index.d.ts file: `src/types/index.d.ts`

```
export {};

declare global {
  interface Window {
    example: string; // whatever type you want to give. (any,number,float etc)
  }
}
```

STEP: 2  add the path to your types directory to your tsconfig.json file.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... rest
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"]
  }
}
```

STEP: 3 Now use it, whereever you want to do it.

```
window.example = 'hello';

console.log(window.example);
```

Comment: Why do you consider this a "HACK SOLUTION"?

Comment: @Fatedx it works really well! i was messing around with so many things but this worked really well so i just said HACK SOLUTION because it resolved the problem. :)

Answer (score 10):

I was facing this issue in my angular code. Below solution helped me to resolve the issue.

I resolved this error by creating a folder name **types** inside **src** and inside that folder created **index.d.ts** file.

the index.d.ts file will have below code.

```
export {};
declare global {
  interface Window {
    chrome: any;  // this will be your variable name
  }
}
```

If the error persists, try adding the path to your types directory to your **tsconfig.json** file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... rest
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

it should be ignored by creating `global.d.ts` file in root of project with this content:

```js
export { }
declare global {
    interface Window {
        [key: string]: any 
    }
}
```

it ignores all variables of `window` object

Answer (score 5):

better still

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    FB: {
      CustomerChat: {
        hide: () => void;
        show: () => void;
      };
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me without declaring it globally

```
declare const window: Window &
   typeof globalThis & {
     FB: any
   }
```

This was the error I was facing `Error: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)` Although mine wasn't really related with your code but this [guide](https://tutorialscamp.com/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-type/) should help you

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming from Next.Js, you need to use `<Script />` inside of `<body>` to load it (loading it inside of the `<Head />` won't work):

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script

Answer (score 0):

Use a temp variable and cast it to any

```
const tempWindow: any = window;
const anyProperty = tempWindow.anyProperty;
```