# TypeScript: Property 'X' does not exist on 'Window & typeof globalThis': suggested solution using 'declare global' gives me error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

### Edit: This is an ESlint problem.  I've included my ESLint setup at the end of this post.

I'm fairly new to TypeScript --  I have been refactoring someone else's React code, moving it to TypeScript for a work project when I ran into this line

```
        const memoryOptionsResponse = window.webchatMethods.getMemory(chatId);
```

TypeScript complains about 'window.webchat', saying

> Property 'X' does not exist on 'Window & typeof globalThis

After some googling, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457935/typescript-error-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-window) would seem to be to put this at the root level of the module

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        webchatMethods:any;
    }
}
```

However now TS complains with the following error.

[This Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript) suggests something similar, but again it has `declare global` and ESLint balks.

After half an hour trying to fix this, I've decided to turn to you for advice -- if anyone knows a good solution, I'd appreciate it!

[image]

```
// .eslintconfig
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true
    }
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "prettier",
    "react",
    "react-hooks"
  ],
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true,
    "mocha": true,
    "browser": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
    "react/prop-types": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "error",
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error",
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": "warn",
    "react/no-find-dom-node": 0,
        "comma-dangle": ["error", "never"],
    "global-require": 0
  }
}
```

---

```
// .eslintignore
test
node_modules
```

Comment: Eslint balks, but does typescript compile and seem to recognize the additional property?

Comment: Yes, It compiles. But I'd prefer that ESLint were happy so that I don't have spurious errors come up, and I don't know what eslint disable command to ñut before the line so that it stops signaling the error...

Comment: Sure. I ask because then the answer (and problem) lies with eslint and not typescript. Can you share information on your eslint setup?

Comment: @DonovanHiland, I've included it at the end of the original post...

Comment: And babel config? :D

Comment: @DonovanHiland -- I have none.  Is there a standard  config you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what's missing is the piece that tells babel how to deal with typescript. I would check out [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/README.md).