# ReactJS- How to set new property on window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a **js** file in my src folder.

```
export default class UserAuth {
...
}
```

In my index.**tsx** file I want to set a new property on window.

```
window.UserAuth = new UserAuth();
```

With this, Iam getting the following error:
`Property 'UserAuth' does not exist on type 'Window'.`

I tried adding the following code in **lib.dom.d.ts** but the error still exists

```
interface Window {
   UserAuth: any;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56458070/10310278 checkout this one

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `window` to `any` and use it dynamically like:

```
const win = (<any>window);
win.UserAuth = new UserAuth();
console.log(win.UserAuth);
```