# Importing Javascript in React TypeScript component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm starting a new React project in TypeScript and its a conversion of an old project that was done in basic JS and HTML. There is a web library written in JS I'm trying to use but I'm not sure how to import it. In the old project it was just imported with a script tag in head. The old function called in the embedded JS was `let external = $pop.render(params)`. The extension for the old import in the script tag was `/index.js?mode=api`. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance! The library is a custom private js library. I have tried `import "URL TO LIBRARY";`, `jQuery.getScript()`, and `import * as Pop from 'URL';`. It is an AMD based module.

Comment: You need to provide a little more information: Which library are you trying to import? What have youried so far?

Comment: Is this private library written as modules? Maybe [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) or [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md) based modules? What does the code look like?

Comment: You can't import from URLs, can you? Webpack will add the module for you if used. You need to download the module to a file and import it from a *file path.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by keeping it as a script tag import in the HTML file then calling the functions I needed from the window `window.$pop.render(params)`. I had to add `declare global { interface Window { $pop:any;}}` so TypeScript knew to expect $pop in window. I got this by cominbing these solutions: [How do I use external script that I add to react JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396307/how-do-i-use-external-script-that-i-add-to-react-js) and [TypeScript error: Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Window'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457935/typescript-error-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-window) .