# window.onmessage not working in react js component

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I have to load react js app in iframe and parent application is sending data to iframe react app using below code:

```
  const myiframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
  myiframe.contentWindow.postMessage('message', '*');


  <iframe id='myIframe' name="my-iframe" src="http://localhost:3000" ></iframe>
```

In iframe app I am trying to receive data:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log('event received')
    }
  }, []);
```

But window.onmessage never triggers or triggers intermittently.

I checked by keeping window.onmessage out of useEffect but it is not working.

Has anyone faced this issue? Need help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you want to try another way? (instead of send message to iframe ) or you have to use send message ?

Comment: I have to communicate with iframe. postMessage is implemented in parent app so I have to add window.onmessage or window.addEventListner('message'). What other way is there?

Comment: in your react source in componentDidMount() {window.parent.callMe = myFunc} and in your parent app just call window.callMe(...your-parameters) if you interested to more, I can show you full sample code

Comment: Thanks, My parent is written in angular. iframe app is in react. Please share example if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple code, not important what is in your iframe and what is in your parent app,
we need just a share a function on a global variable like `window`

in you parent app just call :

```
window.callMe('Hello world');
or
window.callMe({status:true, message:'hello world'});
```

and in your iframe (react in your sample) just define `callMe` on parent window :

```
myFunc=(data)=>{
    console.log(data);
}
window.parent.callMe = myFunc;
```

sample code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const callIframeFunc = () => {
    window.callMe("Hello");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React rel with iframe Demo</h1>
      <iframe
        id="unqiframe"
        title="a"
        srcDoc="<div><script>function myFunc(data){document.getElementsByClassName('testp')[0].innerHTML = 'received data : '+data} window.parent.callMe = myFunc;</script><p class='testp'>No data</p></div>"
        allow="autoplay"
      ></iframe>
      <div>
        <button onClick={callIframeFunc}>Call iFrame Func</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-iframe-demo-forked-ew911)

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting Property 'callMe' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis' error message.

Comment: can you share me you code ? where you defined callMe ?

Comment: I think you are using TypeScript if true then try define like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript or this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457935/typescript-error-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-window

Comment: Hi Babak, thanks for helping out. I was trying some other solution and while debugging I find out that postMessage is running before window.onmessage that is why the event is not receiving.