# property '_env_' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis - React / Typescript ERROR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting this error, I am using React/TypeScript

When I do this, In the conmponent.

```
<p>API_URL: {window._env_.API_URL}</p>
```

I get this error:

```
property '_env_' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis
```

Following this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/

Comment: You need to declare it: [TypeScript error: Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Window'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457935/typescript-error-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-window)

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, posting answer for other. Very helpful.

```
declare const window: any;

export const MyComponent= () => {
  
  console.log("In Login");
  try {
    console.log("widow[API_URL]: " + window._env_.API_URL);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

return (
    <div> Test DIV </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to use prefix (REACT_APP) and after for accessing the env file, you have to use proccess

```
<p>API_URL: {process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}</p>
```

Comment: I have seen this before, although this is more to do with a Typescript error. Windows Type