# Convert Firestore timestamp into a date format

Tags: typescript, date, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs

I have a service that obtains certain data from a BehaviorSubject.

```
this.myData.album$.value.album_date;
```

When console logging the returned date from firestore with:

```
console.log(this.myData.album$.value.album_date);
```

The console reads:

```
Timestamp {seconds: 1572263054, nanoseconds: 63000000}
```

What I need to do is convert this value inside one of my functions and manipulate it into any format, such as "Monday, 28th October 2019".

Unfortunately given my requirement i cannot use the `toDate() |` inside the HTML and this needs to be achieved within my function.

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have `moment` available to use within my Typescript file.
I am using `Angular 8` and `Firestore`

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late to the party, but I've encountered the same issue.

Here is my solution, although not pretty because of the use of `any`, but it worked for me:

```
(myAlbumDate as any).toDate()
```

Now TypeScript doesn't complain anymore and the production building passes without errors.

**Update**

Today I found myself in the same scenario and because the `any` type scratches my brain I tried to find a more elegant solution and I found it on [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12709880/11881804) and I applied it to my use case.

The solution is to extend the `Date` interface like so:

```
declare global {
  interface Date {
    toDate: () => Date;
  }
}
```

Now I have IntelliSense and no more `any` or errors in my Angular template.

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#to-date

You need to use Firebase to get the date within your function, and then pass the date to your html:

```
console.log(this.myData.album$.value.album_date.toDate());
```

I think may work

Comment: An update - This works in development environment. However the 'toDate()' is underlined in red by typescript. The error being `Property 'toDate' does not exist on type 'Date'.ts(2339)`. Building in production fails unfortunately.