# TypeScript: Object is possibly 'null'. window.open

Tags: typescript

How does one make this work in Typescript?

`window.open(externalUrl, '_blank').focus();`

this throws the following typescript error:

`Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)`

I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
if (typeof window != 'undefined' && window && externalUrl !== '' && window.open(externalUrl, '_blank') ) {
      window.open(externalUrl, '_blank').focus();
    }
```

Comment: window object is only available in browser.

Comment: what does `open(...)` returns ?

Comment: `window.open(...)?.focus()` - "optional chaining" operator `?.`

Comment: @MarkusZeller that should be taken care of by the if statement,  no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you explicitly set a new property on \`window\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

Comment: @Monkpit this solution would only work in typescript 3.7+

Comment: @Nicolas returns an object like this: blur: ƒ ()
close: ƒ ()
closed: false
focus: ƒ ()
frames: global {window: global, self: global, location: Location, closed: false, frames: global, …}
length: 0
location: Location {}
opener: Window {parent: Window, postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, …}
parent: global {window: global, self: global, location: Location, closed: false,

Comment: pre 3.7 it could be `const w = window.open(externalUrl, '_blank'); if (w) w.focus();`; the issue is that `window.open()` could return `null` and you need to save its value if you want to check it and then use it; you can't check one call to `window.open()` for `null` and have it imply anything for other calls.

Comment: @jcalz this is the answer,  submit it as an answer and i will select it--- thanks!

Comment: @MarkusZeller this isn't really the same problem as the post you suggest Markus,  I am not trying to add a new property to the window

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming you're using an IDE, there's probably a red squiggly line that shows which part of the expression is the problem:

```
  window.open(externalUrl, '_blank').focus(); // error
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//Object is possibly 'null'
```

Here, it's saying that `window.open(externalUrl, '_blank')` is possibly `null`, not that `window` itself might be.  So you don't have to check `window` to address this particular error (although depending on the runtime JS environment you're using there may or may not be a `window`.  I'll assume there is one).

Anyway, the error you're seeing comports with the [MDN documentation for `Window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Return_value), which says that if the window can't be opened the return value will be `null`.  To address this, you need to look at the return value, and only call `focus()` on it if it's not null.  Note that you *can't* do it this way:

```
if (window.open(externalUrl, '_blank')) {
    window.open(externalUrl, '_blank').focus(); // still error
}
```

That's because the compiler does not believe that one successful call to `window.open()` implies that a second call will also be successful.  As far as the compiler knows, it's possible that the first call returns a `Window` and the second call returns `null`.  That seems unlikely to me if you're calling it with the same arguments, but I can't say *for certain* that it would work.  And besides, you don't *really* want to open two windows, do you?

---

So, how *should* we do it?  A way that works with most version of TypeScript is just to save the result in a variable and test it:

```
const w = window.open(externalUrl, '_blank');
if (w) {
    w.focus(); // okay now
}
```

In TypeScript 3.7 and up, there's support for the [optional chaining operator, `?.`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining).  This lets you write the above more tersely as:

```
window.open(externalUrl, '_blank')?.focus(); // okay also
```

Eventually you can expect the optional chaining operator to be part of JavaScript itself; until then, the above code emits to JavaScript as something like:

```
// JavaScript emitted 
(_a = window.open(externalUrl, '_blank')) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.focus();
```

which saves the result of `window.open()` into a variable (like we did with `w` above) and then only calls `focus()` on it if it's not `null` or `undefined`.  Anyway, either way should work for you.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBTAHlDAnMAQwBsBVPYgLkQGco8YwBzASkQG8AoRHxAd0YATOHwB0cAA4YwmHPiJkKAGkQByAPoAjYoTABrVS1EoIIGmhYBuRAHobifHjh5uvOwD9PX7z99-vrjx2APKaAFYY0IgwNIgScDQ0MNoAnmpgIMTEqpyB0cCIaAJgwmKS0rK4BCTkxCoa2roGLGxcvO38QiLiUjLYVQq19Vo6+obGcKbmVrb2dDBZDnhOLu0AvrntEAh0-IgAvJ0l3eV9ctWKdWojTYaWeTAFRa157WImZhbWdohweoRpMAiPIbPLFUo9Cr9eQ1ZTXRpjFgAfgmUy+s1+-zSJBocE4oMQQA)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @jcalz's excellent answer, there is also one-liner, using `!`:

`window.open(externalUrl, '_blank')!.focus();`

Comment: `!` asserts that the value is not null. That is not the same as passing the `if` check. But there is an equivalent, which would be `window.open(externalUrl, '_blank')?.focus();` In this case `focus()` will only be run if the object is not null.