# Reach global window variable from index.html in a Vue component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, stenciljs

If i have an Stencil.js component that i load in to my Vue project like this:

**index.html:**

```
  <script type="module"
    src="https://xxxxxx.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/topbar.esm.js">
  </script>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener('topbarLoaded', function (data) {
      window.topbar = data.detail;
      console.log('topbar was loaded and here it is:', window.topbar);
    });
  </script>
```

I then want to reach the topbar information in my vue components. 
Something like

**VueComponent.vue**

```
<script lang="ts">
   import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

   @Component({
     name: 'testcomp'
   })
   export default class PodList extends Vue {
      data() {
         return {
            topbar: window.topbar // Error: Property 'topbar' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

So here I want all stuff i have from my topbar to be accessible in my Vue component. 
As it is now, if I open Chrome devtools i can write topbar.user and get all information of user, but I also want this information to be reachable in all vue components.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just listen to that even from within your component?

Comment: True, I moved it to my main.ts. 
I want to set an axios header with a token that the topbar is fetching. 
So now i moved to eventListener to main.ts, and that sets header like this: 
`axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = await topbar.access_token();`

Here is the code in main.ts: 

`window.addEventListener('topbarLoaded', async function (data) {
  const topbar = (data as any);
  var topbarDetails = topbar.detail;
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = await topbarDetails.access_token();
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript doesn't know that property. You can solve that in several ways:

1. Add `// @ts-ignore` on the previous line. This suppresses errors on the next line.
2. Cast to `any`: `(window as any).topbar`
3. [Define the property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12709074) in the `window` interface:

```
declare global {
    interface Window { topbar: any; }
}
```

Comment: Solution 3 is what I would have recommended as well because it gives you the option to add the actual type declaration for `topbar`, and it makes it clear that `topbar` is something that has been added to the global scope.