# How do you explicitly set a new property on `global` in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a variable defined like this:

```
(global as any).State = {
  variables: {},
};
```

My question is, how do I declare the type signature of `State`?  If I say `(global as any).State: Something = ...`, the compiler gives me an error saying `; expected`.

As far as I can tell, it's the same question as this one, but it's about the `window` variable, not the `global` variable: [How do you explicitly set a new property on `window` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

Comment: I think, `; expected` has rather something to do with [JS ASI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion). Try to insert a semicolon before above code snippet and it also should work (though without strong types).

Answer (score 1):

[`global`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/27123c0/types/node/globals.d.ts#L144) is the Node.JS equivalent of `window` and a global variable declaration contained in `@types/node`:

```
// @types/node/globals.d.ts
declare var global: NodeJS.Global;
```

Augment `global` from inside a module file:

```
export {}

declare global { // declare global is TS specific, it is not the Node global!
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      State: {
        variables: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Augment `global` from inside a script  file (without `export`/`import`):

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    State: {
      variables: {}
    }
  }
}
```

You will then be able to set `State` without relying on `any`:

```
global.State = { variables: {} }
```