# use js object in typescript that has been loaded earlier in <script> node

Tags: typescript

I have a web app written in TypeScript and bundled with webpack. There is a config file that is pure javascript that simply sets an object like this:

```js
var productsConfig = {
  "de": {
    currencySymbolPrefix: "",
    currencySymbolSuffix: " &euro;", // space plus €
    currencySeparator: ",",
    products: {
      "1": { productTitle: "Product 1", productPrice: "0.95", productSize: "200g", productImgUrl: "img/1.jpg" },
      "2": { productTitle: "Product 2", productPrice: "0.95", productSize: "200g", productImgUrl: "img/2.jpg" },
    }
  }
};
```

This file is not bundled with webpack with the rest of the app, it is loaded within the html:

```html
<script src="product_config.js"></script>
```

How can I use the `productsConfig` object and its contents in TypeScript? If I declare it in TypeScript with

```js
declare const productsConfig: any;
```

then I can use it but the original contents are reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typescript, `declare` doesn't affect the runtime at all, which you can see in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gBxk4ArmBmgMKoBmAlgOYBc8UKAngNwBQQA).

Because typescript uses a module system, the `productsConfig` variable is not globally scoped, which is why that's not working.

To access the variable you defined, you can use the `window` object: `window.productsConfig`.

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        productsConfig: any;
    }
}
```

See more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12709074/2178159).