# How to edit a global type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

`window.getComputedStyle` returns a value with type `CSSStyleDeclaration`, which has CSS properties keys in camelcase format.

However, tested both on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, it returns the keys' values in both camelcase, and hyphen separated format, and I reference the keys with hyphen separated format:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div#test');
const computedStyles = window.getComputedStyle(div);

console.log(
  'marginTop:', computedStyles.marginTop,
  'margin-top:', computedStyles['margin-top']
);
```

```css
div#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

It causes me a need to use a lot of ugly `as unknown as ...` when trying to get a value referencing a key (like the second case in the above example), so I've decided to add extra properties to `CSSStyleDeclaration`. I'm just not sure how to do it.

And just to make it crystal clear: the issue is that on `CSSStyleDeclaration` (the return type of `window.getComputedStyle`) `margin-top` as property doesn't exist, but the return value actually has it.

What would worth mentioning is I wouldn't like to create new, custom types. Basically I would just like to extend an already existing type, so `CSSStyleDeclaration` locally would have the keys already existed on it, plus my own (`margin-top` based on the example).

Comment: Where would you need to use `as unknown as` when you think it could be done otherwise? Iam not sure about your problem, based on the code you provided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you explicitly set a new property on \`window\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to simply redeclare the type in a `.d.ts` file. It keeps the original properties, and add the new ones as well. Based on the example it looks like this:

```
declare interface CSSStyleDeclaration {
  'margin-top': string;
}
```