# Explicitly setting type on window for Intercom in Typescript throws error

Tags: typescript

As per the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript), I have had to extend the window object in order to strongly type Intercom's window functionality.

Originally the code used to look like this:

```
  setCurrentRoute() {
    if (
      this.currentRoute.getValue().indexOf('website') > -1 ||
      this.currentRoute.getValue().indexOf('builder') > -1
    ) {
      (window as any).Intercom('update', {
        hide_default_launcher: true,
      });
    } else {
      (window as any).Intercom('update', {
        hide_default_launcher: false,
      });
    }
    localStorage.setItem('currentRoute', this.currentRoute.getValue());
  }
```

But as I am trying to leverage more of Typescript's type safety features, it now looks like this:

```
  declare global {
    interface Window {
      Intercom(update: string, params: { hide_default_launcher: boolean }): void;
    }
  }

  setCurrentRoute(): void {
    if (this.currentRoute.getValue().indexOf('website') > -1 || this.currentRoute.getValue().indexOf('builder') > -1) {
      this.window.Intercom('update', {
        'hide_default_launcher': true
      });
    } else {
      this.window.Intercom('update', {
        'hide_default_launcher': false
      });
    }
    localStorage.setItem('currentRoute', this.currentRoute.getValue());
  }
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Intercom' of undefined
    at RouterService.push../src/app/shared/services/router.service.ts.RouterService.setCurrentRoute
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Why `this.window.` and not just `window.` as in first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by doing the following:

```
export interface RouterWindow extends Window {
  Intercom(update: string, params: { hide_default_launcher: boolean }): void;
}

  setCurrentRoute(): void {
    if (this.currentRoute.getValue().indexOf('website') > -1 || this.currentRoute.getValue().indexOf('builder') > -1) {
      (<RouterWindow>window).Intercom('update', {
        'hide_default_launcher': true
      });
    } else {
      (<RouterWindow>window).Intercom('update', {
        'hide_default_launcher': false
      });
    }
    localStorage.setItem('currentRoute', this.currentRoute.getValue());
  }
```

Answer (score 14):

### Intercom With Typescript

Here's how I got typescript and intercom working:

1. Include dependency `yarn add -D @types/intercom-web`
2. Edit your `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ....,
    "types": [...., "@types/intercom-web"]
  }
}
```

3. Now types will show in your code when referencing `window.Intercom` and the namespace `Intercom_` will be globally available e.g: `Intercom_.IntercomSettings`

Comment: This *almost* worked for me.  I ended up having to explicitly provide the path to the file in the node_modules folder: `[path to node modules]/node_modules/@types/intercom-web/index.d.ts`