# using javascript globalThis for state management

Tags: javascript, global-variables

It seems like a crazy idea, but is there any problem if I use globalThis to store the global state of my browser only SPA.

I am thinking of something like this

```
globalThis.state = {...initialStateData}; // attach a property to globalThis and initialize
//later in any component, mutate the value
globalThis.state.counter = 45;
//yet in some other area, access and display the value
console.log(globalThis.state.counter);
```

This can be taken further by introducing proxies into the mix and create something like a light weight redux.

I tested this in chrome, and it works (by works I mean chrome had no objection on me attaching my data to globalThis).

My question is, is it a crazy idea and should not be used in a production app because of some standards that I might be violating in ignorance?

Or perhaps, behaviour of globalThis is gonna change over time and browsers will not allow user-attached attributes to this specific object?

EDIT: This question is about pure vanilla JS and not about redux or react or even typescript.

[How to define global variable in Deno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62286838/how-to-define-global-variable-in-deno) will be the closest match to the current query

Comment: It will work ... but it's insecure, besides, Redux's main feature of **Refreshing|Rerendering components on state change** will not be there...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with global state if it fits with what you need, but it is rarely necessary for that global state to be a property on the global object. Assuming you are using a module system, which is really a good idea, then you can have your global state be an export of the module and import it into any file where you need it.

Comment: It's not secure, the user might update the state according to his/her need, which can lead to some major security concerns.

Comment: If you *really, really, really* need a global state (**really!**), then at least assign *an object* to the global object, and add properties to that object. But only do that if you *really* have to!

Comment: Why is everyone saying it's insecure? Yes global state is bad, but a user already has full power over their browser - they can already modify anything they want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally not recommended to modify globalThis (or window) for the following reasons:

- **Naming Conflicts with 3rd party code**: If another script also modifies globalThis and chooses the same name, you're in trouble, though this applies more to libraries than the main page's logic.
- **Naming Conflicts with Javascript**: New built-in javascript utilities tend to get added to the global object - if they ever added one with the same name you're using, it'll cause issues, both in your page, and any library you use that expects that utility to be there. *However*, as long as your name is unique enough, this really isn't a big issue.
- **Versioning**: If you're developing a library, there are unfortunately scenarios where you might have multiple versions of the same library loaded at once. This is not possible if they use global state. Again, this doesn't really apply to use as you're not developing a library.
- **Traceability**: It's difficult to know what sets the global state and what modifies it.

So, in all honesty, you can probably get away with using global state and not face any of those negative consequences. I don't want to just tell you not to use it simply because that's the recommended advice. In fact, back in the day, it used to be more common for websites to put all of their data and modules into one giant global hierarchy. *However*, I would still recommend avoiding global state for one other reason - A better solution exists that's less magical. Javascript now has a standard module system that can be used in place of global state. Just create a module to hold whatever shared state your application has.

Comment: thanks, I could smell my approach had some problem but couldn't figure out what, and now I can see what could be coming my way if I go this route.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the `globalThis` or the `window` object of browser is quit non-conventional & it would create some issues that'd be hard to debug or fix.. Also this is one kind of object pollution & eslint/jshint will also complain about & typescript will throw Compile Time Error.. Don't do this in production as it'd be very bad in the long run.. One of them is **conflicting property names** & there are many problem that will arise. I don't know each & every one of them but you can easily read some medium books/articles about this behavior. Also that's why modern npm packages doesn't touch these objects as `globalThis` doesn't allow the idea of `modules`... Try using `globalThis`/`window` as `read-only` objects.. Don't mutate the props of it..

Hope you understand what I said..