# REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE Error in VStudio with Yarn build

Tags: reactjs, redux, electron-builder

I'm trying to build my app (using Redux and electron) with : yarn build

I get this error on Windows :

> Property '**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE**' does not exist on type 'Window &
> typeof globalThis'

the error is in this block of code that I use for the configuration of Redux :

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
export const store = createStore( persistedReducer,
 composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
);
```

how can I correct it ?

Comment: Could this be an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript

Comment: thanks for your reply but I don't see anything helpful there ... can you be more precise ? please.

Comment: As you are using TS when you are trying to access a property on `window` that doesn't exist in `Window` type declaration. The compiler will error.
There are several things you can do, you can try to use `@ts-ignore` so the compiler doesn't error or you can make extend window declaration with new property

Comment: Also you can try to do it like that: `<any>window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__`

Comment: it was a good solution, thanks. but because I'm using a tsx format the exact solution was (window as any) and not <any>window

Comment: @SerhiiYukhnevych can you please post your solution as an answer and not like a comment ? like that I can close this post as finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using TS when you are trying to access a property on window that doesn't exist in Window type declaration. The compiler will error. There are several things you can do, you can try to use @ts-ignore so the compiler doesn't error or you can make extend window declaration with new property.
Also you can try to do it like that: `<any>window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` or `window as any` if you are using .tsx