# webpack/babel : what is the best way to share variables between bundles?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have 2 separate js bundles that load on the same html page, so webpack.config.js:

```
entry: {
  preload: "./preload.tsx",
  main: "./index.tsx"
}
```

> GOAL: preload.js produces a Promise of a cache table that needs to be accessed by main.js.

But they need to be separate bundles, so `import` won't work which will lead to execution of preload.js twice. I've tried to:

- add a global variable (couldn't figure out where the actual definition should go so `Uncaught ReferenceError: global_variable is not defined`
- add an extra property to window obejct (couldn't figure out how to make it work with TypeScript 3.9. Tried pretty much everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12709074/456933) and more. The only thing that worked was `(window as any)` which looks evil
- I don't want hacky workarounds like using LocalStorage or DOM manipulation.

I couldn't find a decent solution as of TypeScript 3.9. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: The safest solution would be to use the dynamic [`import()`](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) but global variables can be defined in a [.d.ts file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html) and then included with `"types":["<your type folder>", "node_modules/@types"]` in the tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

Like @Elias mentioned in a comment I think a prefer solution is a dynamic import one, but to answer the Question, **You can do one of two things**:

**1.** Use **[ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/)**:

```
plugins: [
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      globalVar: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'src/GlobalVarModule'))
   });
]
```

GlobalBarModule.ts:

```
var globalVar = "my global var value"
module.exports = globalVar;
```

And simple usage:
Index.js:

```
console.log(globalVar);
```

> Whenever the identifier (`globalVar`) is encountered as free variable in a module, the module is loaded automatically and the identifier is filled with the exports of the loaded module (or property in order to support named exports).

-From Docs.

**2.** Use **[Externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)** to let webpack know your are consuming a variable from the window:

```
externals: {
  globalVar: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'src/GlobalVarModule'))
}
```

Somewhere early in your code:

```
globalVar = "my global var value";
```

Usage:

```
import globalVar from 'globalVar';

console.log(globalVar);
```