# Get rid of any when using Material-UI Autocomplete with Google Maps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, autocomplete, material-ui

In Material-UI documentation there is an [example of how to use Autocomplete with Google Maps.](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#google-maps-place)

Everything works fine, but there are couple of `any`. My project has strict policies on using `any`, so I would like to get rid of them (or have justification if it's unavoidable).

While I could get rid of some of them, in this part I couldn't find a solution how to remove or replace them with proper types.

```
if (!autocompleteService.current && (window as any).google) {
  autocompleteService.current = new (window as any).google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
}
```

Is there a way to avoid using `any` here?

(Here is [link to Autocomplete demo on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3qip?file=/demo.tsx:2103-2272))

Comment: this may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript