# Web3.js extending the window interface type definitions

Tags: typescript, ethereum, web3js

Web3.js web3 into the `window` object.

Browser Wallets like MetaMask inject ethereum into the `window` object.

In typescript right now to mitigate compile errors I'm casting as follows `(window as any).ethereum`

After looking in the Web3 repository and Wallet repos (such as MetaMask) there are no importable / copyable typescript definitions / interfaces for the `Window` object.

A possible solution is to write my own interface and extend the Window, *look at the Window object and try to infer the types - not ideal*

Other developers that have used web3.js and typescript, how did you get past the Window type interface issues and intellisense suggestions in VS Code?

Comment: Technically, `window.ethereum` is injected by MetaMask or any other in-browser wallet. Note that other wallets **do not** have `window.ethereum`. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/connecting-the-wallet-of-a-user-to-your-dapp-web3-js-project-and-interacting-w

Comment: Thanks @MikkoOhtamaa i'm assuming that the most popular and adopted wallets are the one's that will inject it into the browser.

Comment: You are assuming incorrect. Only browser plugin wallets can inject `ethereum` and most wallets are mobile wallets.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa i've updated the question to reflect your explanation, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: And your question is still very valid :) But it might be a better ask a generic question "How toa add new `window` variables in TypeScript". Because that is what you want to do, there is nothing Ethereum specific in your question.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Sorry, but the question I have isn't around extending the interface of the `Window` that is relatively simple to do as documented here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript

I'm more interested in how other developers have handled the issue of Web3.js's and MetaMasks's lack of typings for extending the window object.

I was digging around the Web3.js repository and found some typings that include the functions available on `window.ethereum` so that might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I came across this just recently as well. I could not find an appropriate [typings package from DefinitelyTyped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/dt/search?search=ethereum) so I started extrapolating from my own usage and the [Metamask Documentation](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html) and created something that works so far.

**Perhaps the community could edit this answer with their own contributions.**

In order to use the `ethereum` object without TS complaints, I declare it in the window object:

```js
declare global {
    interface Window {
        ethereum: Ethereumish;
    }
}
```

The makeshift Ethereum Provider types, `Ethereumish` looks like this:

```js
import { ProviderMessage, ProviderRpcError, ProviderConnectInfo, RequestArguments } from 'hardhat/types';

export interface EthereumEvent {
    connect: ProviderConnectInfo;
    disconnect: ProviderRpcError;
    accountsChanged: Array<string>;
    chainChanged: string;
    message: ProviderMessage
}

type EventKeys = keyof EthereumEvent;
type EventHandler<K extends EventKeys> = (event: EthereumEvent[K]) => void;

export interface Ethereumish {
    autoRefreshOnNetworkChange: boolean;
    chainId: string;
    isMetaMask?: boolean;
    isStatus?: boolean;
    networkVersion: string;
    selectedAddress: any;

    on<K extends EventKeys>(event: K, eventHandler: EventHandler<K>): void;
    enable(): Promise<any>;
    request?: (request: { method: string, params?: Array<any> }) => Promise<any>
    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    send?: (request: { method: string, params?: Array<any> }, callback: (error: any, response: any) => void) => void
    sendAsync: (request: RequestArguments) => Promise<unknown>
}
```

As you can see, I have not been able to figure out the exact types of many things so far, but the important methods, `send` and `sendAsync` are accurate in my experience.

Another useful template is something I found inside @ethersproject/providers/src.ts/web3-provider.ts

```js
export type ExternalProvider = {
    isMetaMask?: boolean;
    isStatus?: boolean;
    host?: string;
    path?: string;
    sendAsync?: (request: { method: string, params?: Array<any> }, callback: (error: any, response: any) => void) => void
    send?: (request: { method: string, params?: Array<any> }, callback: (error: any, response: any) => void) => void
    request?: (request: { method: string, params?: Array<any> }) => Promise<any>
}
```

this can be used when loading a new provider

```js
new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(myProvider: ExternalProvider)
```

Comment: This repo from metamask seems to provide the type definition `MetaMaskInpageProvider`: https://github.com/MetaMask/providers

Comment: it seems very heavy to import hardhat into client dev just for the type definitions.

Answer (score 30):

The official Metamask Provider repo now exports types you could/should use for extending the Window interface.

Same as in @Felipe's answer with `MetamaskInpageProvider` instead of `Ethereumish`, add the following to a Typescript declaration file in your project.

```js
// metamask.d.ts
import { MetaMaskInpageProvider } from "@metamask/providers";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum: MetaMaskInpageProvider;
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to use `ethereum?: MetaMaskInpageProvider;` for this to work for me. Note the ?

Comment: Could you provide the filename and location this should be placed in? This would prove useful for the less experienced.

Comment: Made it clear it should go in a Typescript declaration file @bart-kosmala

Answer (score 2):

My friends, if you are using **`React`** with **`TypeScript`** just do this and everything goes right! **Trust me :)**

1. create **`global.d.ts`** in the root of your project and put this code

   ```
    declare global {
        interface Window {
            ethereum: import('ethers').providers.ExternalProvider;
        }
    }
   ```
2. Then in **`react-app-env.d.ts`** put this code

   ```
    interface Window {
        ethereum: any;
    }
   ```

Now you have the code snippet and no error!!

Answer (score 1):

I will just dump what I use currently here.

###### `src/{anything}.ts` e.g. `src/interfaces.d.ts`

```
interface Window {
  // pick one
  ethereum: EthereumProvider
  // ethereum: ExternalProvider
  // ethereum: AbstractProvider
}

// ExternalProvider seems to be the official ethersproject type for the window.ethereum object, however, `new Web3(ethereum)` does not like it so we must improvise.
declare type ExternalProvider = import('@ethersproject/providers').ExternalProvider
declare type AbstractProvider = import('web3/node_modules/web3-core/types').AbstractProvider
interface EthereumProvider extends ExternalProvider {
  _state: {
    accounts: string[]
  }
  on(event: 'close' | 'accountsChanged' | 'chainChanged' | 'networkChanged', callback: (payload: any) => void): void
  once(event: 'close' | 'accountsChanged' | 'chainChanged' | 'networkChanged', callback: (payload: any) => void): void
  removeAllListeners(): void
  sendAsync: AbstractProvider['sendAsync']
}
```

This file is a script as it does not import and export anything (unlike module), making its declarations ambient - available globally. Just make sure it is included in the `tsconfig.json` file in the include/blob array `"include": ["..."]`.

More reading:
https://github.com/MetaMask/providers
[github.com~ethers.js @ ExternalProvider](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/73a46efea32c3f9a4833ed77896a216e3d3752a0/packages/providers/src.ts/web3-provider.ts#L13)