# How do I resolve "ethereum.request cannot find name 'ethereum'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ethereum, web3js

I'm using metamask/detect-provider to make a simple button that connects to the metamask extension following the metamask documentation. However, it returns

> Typescript error Cannot find name 'ethereum'. TS3204 when I do npm start. Does anyone know the reason for this error?

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
import { Message, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const loadMetamask = () => {
    ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <h1>Testing</h1>

        <Message warning>Metamask is not connected</Message>
        <button color="green"
          onClick={() => loadMetamask()}
        >Connect to Metamask</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to typescript compiler couldn't find the `ethereum` module as `ethereum` module is in global `window`.

There are few ways to solve it.

First way, create your own type definition for `window.ethereum`. You may refer to here [Web3.js extending the window interface type definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504958/web3-js-extending-the-window-interface-type-definitions)

Second way, ask typescript compiler to ignore the error, which is ***not recommended*** as it beat the purpose of using typescript.

```
//@ts-ignore
 ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
```

Last way, which is the laziest way. `@metamask/provides` did provide the type definition for `window.ethereum`. Therefore, we install it by running

```
npm i @metamask/providers
```

After that, import the class

```
import { MetaMaskInpageProvider } from '@metamask/providers';
```

Then, tell the typescript compiler to treat `window.ethereum` as `MetaMaskInpageProvider`

```
const ethereum = window.ethereum as MetaMaskInpageProvider;
```

Now, you should be able to

```
ethereum.request<string[]>({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
```

Your code should looks similar to below

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
import { Message, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider';
import { MetaMaskInpageProvider } from '@metamask/providers';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const loadMetamask = async () => {
    // You need to await for user response on the metamask popup dialog
    const accounts = await ethereum.request<string[]>({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
    if(accounts){
       console.log(accounts[0]);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <h1>Testing</h1>

        <Message warning>Metamask is not connected</Message>
        <button color="green"
          onClick={() => loadMetamask()}
        >Connect to Metamask</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Even though it works, but we installed unused `@metamask/providers` library.