# While avoiding the TS error "Property 'request' does not exist on type 'EthereumProvider'" I encounter bug, "all declarations...identical modifiers"

Tags: typescript, ethereum, metamask

I am trying to supply types to TypeScript type checking. This is so that I can bypass `Property 'request' does not exist on type 'EthereumProvider'` like whats descriebd in the link below.

Specifically for `window.ethereum` I am trying to enable it by going:

```
import { MetaMaskInpageProvider } from "@metamask/providers";

// later...
declare global {
    interface Window {
        ethereum: MetaMaskInpageProvider;
        // ethereum: any;
    }
}
```

Like that.

But I get:

```
(property) Window.ethereum?: MetaMaskInpageProvider
All declarations of 'ethereum' must have identical modifiers.ts(2687)
```

This code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504958/web3-js-extending-the-window-interface-type-definitions).

I don't understand "must have identical modifiers." What's that mean?

I don't have any other interfaces defining `ethereum`. So thats not it.

I also only reference "ethereum" in my code by going `window.ethereum.doSomething`

Any ideas?

Also I can't recreate this error because I have no idea how it came to be in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to throw in a ?

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        ethereum?: MetaMaskInpageProvider; // note the ?
    }
}
```