# Angular 9 test error NullInjectorError: No provider for Window

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have started to write my tests for an Angular 9 app.  I followed the advice given by Jeff Camera about half way down this post:

[How do you explicitly set a new property on `window` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

If you need to extend the window object with a custom type that requires the use of import you can use the following method:

> window.d.ts
>
> import MyInterface from './MyInterface';
>
> declare global {
> interface Window {
> propName: MyInterface
> } }

I am not getting this error when I run ng test.

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AdvancedsearchService -> AuthService -> Window -> Window]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Window!
```

Here is my spec.ts for the component in question

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AdvancedSearchComponent } from './advanced-search.component';

import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';


describe('AdvancedSearchComponent', () => {
  let component: AdvancedSearchComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AdvancedSearchComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [ AdvancedSearchComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AdvancedSearchComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I am not sure where I am supposed to add the provider for Window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you added Window to your module provider ?
This error says you have used window but it is not defined in your module.ts

Example:

providers: [
Window
],

it should be the same for AdvancedsearchService AuthService

Comment: I think you are correct.  I added some code to the providers in the TestBed config.
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
          declarations: [ AdvancedSearchComponent ],
          providers: [{
          provide: Window,
          useValue: window
        }]
        })
        .compileComponents();
      }));

I am not getting some errors related to "TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined" but I believe that is out of scope for this question.  Thank you