# Typescript errors out when using window variable within a component

Tags: typescript, spartacus-storefront

In my angular component, I have to access a variable defined in window scope. For that, I have defined like below.

```
if (this.window.nativeWindow.KAMPYLE_ONSITE_SDK) {
  console.log(' sureveyDisplayed :- ' + this.window.nativeWindow.KAMPYLE_ONSITE_SDK.isSurveyDisplayed());
  console.log(' updatePageView :- ' + this.window.nativeWindow.KAMPYLE_ONSITE_SDK.updatePageView());
}
```

After adding this, typescript throws compilation error

> error TS2339: Property 'KAMPYLE_ONSITE_SDK' does not exist on type 'Window'.

I understand that typescript cannot find this variable defined anywhere but can anyone tell me how to embed a variable defined in window scope into a angular component?

Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: possible duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. In our case, this variable is loaded by a third-party javascript file. Until this file is loaded, we won't have this variable available.