# Errors with React.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am working on integrating maps in my react project. I am getting some errors. I used typescript in my project.

Below is a code which shows error:

```
handleChange = (e:any) => {
    this.setState({location: this.state.location})
     function initAutocomplete() {
       var input = document.getElementById('pac-input')! as HTMLInputElement;
       var searchBox = new window.google.maps.places.SearchBox(input); 
       searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
         this.setState({ PlaceName: document.getElementById('pac-input').value });
               ^//---------------------#1
       });
     }
   
     initAutocomplete();
 }
```

This is error which I am facing:

#1 : Property 'setState' does not exist on type 'SearchBox'.ts(2339)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you explicitly set a new property on \`window\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

For a brief checking I think you're loosing a `this` context here. Try to use arrow function for `initAutocomplete`: `const initAutocomplete = () => {...}`

Answer (score 0):

annonymous function decleration create their own `this` object - you could fix you're code in 2 ways:

- change it to an arrow function ( arrow functions inherit the outer `this` object)

or

```
   const that = this;
   searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
     that.setState({ PlaceName: document.getElementById('pac-input').value });
   });
```