# How to use contextBridge in React-Electron?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, electron

I'm trying to connect with preload and frame.tsx
But, It isn't working.

frame.tsx

```
function handleButtonClick(id: string) {
    window.electron.send("requestWindowChange", "data") // Error part
    if(id === 'maximize') {
        setIsMaximize(!isMaximize)
    }
}
```

I simply add it. and...

preload.ts

```
import {contextBridge, ipcRenderer} from 'electron'

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
    send: (channel:string, data) => {
        let normalChannels = ['requestWindowChange']
        if (normalChannels.includes(channel)) {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, data)
        }
    },
    receive: (channel:string, func) => {
        let normalChannels = ['responseWindowChange']
        if (normalChannels.includes(channel)) {
            ipcRenderer.on(channel, (_event, data) => func(data))
        }
    }
})
```

Also, I'm already making 'preload.ts' to 'preload.js' by using 'tsc' command.

Finally, here is the electron.ts

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 720,
    width: 1280,
    minHeight: 300,
    minWidth: 450,
    frame: false,
    show: false,
    center: true,
    fullscreen: false,
    kiosk: !isDev,
    resizable: true,
    webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
    }
})
```

I only copy necessary part.
If you need more code, please comment here.
I really don't know why It isn't working.

- Here is Error Message.

> any Property 'electron' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof
> globalThis'. Did you mean 'Electron'?ts(2551)

Comment: I don't know much Typescript but you might have to declare the new API you added to the window object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12709880/13752696

Comment: @Foxeared Thank you for your help! I'm not sure I know this, but thank to your comment, I can get a hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm trying searching and asking for a week, finally I find it.
Just add this at frame.tsx.

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        api? : any
    }
}
```

What a simple it is...

Comment: By the way, you should mark your answer as correct if it solved your issue.

Comment: @Foxeared Oh, I got it! Thanks!