# property "x" does not exist in type "y"

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add a method to an object, like so:

```
Y.prototype.x = function(){return 'x'}
```

And getting:

```
Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Y'
```

After googling and searching, I am still clueless tbh.

Comment: Do you get that error when adding `x` or is it when you try to read `x` later?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you explicitly set a new property on \`window\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)

Comment: What you are writing is javascript. You also need to add the type info to 'Y'. How you do that depends on where Y is defined. Search typescript module augmentation.

Comment: Your question is very open. You need to provide more input of what is your current code. How is Y declared and what value does it already contain? How is it created?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mLL6vm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.